# ASCII Library for Creating "Pretty" Directory Trees?

Tags: php, unix, tree, ascii

Is there some *nix tool or perl/php library that will let you easily create directory tree visualizations that look like the following?

```
www
|-- private
|    |-- app 
|    |    |-- php
|    |    |    |-- classes
|    |    |    +-- scripts
|    |    |-- settings
|    |    +-- sql
|    +-- lib
|         +-- ZendFramework-HEAD
+-- public
    |-- css
    |-- images
    +-- scripts
```

Comment: If anyone is looking for this solution on Windows (I was!), you can simply type `tree` at the command line.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

How about this example from [Unix Tree / Linux Tree](http://www.centerkey.com/tree/):

```
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

Comment: You gotta love a one-liner

Comment: That's disgustingly awesome, but part of what I like about the output above is how it's not all dashes to the files, you get those pipes connecting subdirectories vertically

Comment: You might check this person's solution out then: http://sandeep-vaniya.blogspot.com/2008/04/perl-script-for-directory-tree.html

Comment: great! although not quite right output (I'm not critizing so much as adding constuctive critism) - the files in sub-directories are all being group together when I tried it?

Comment: Does anyone know how you would add to that script so that it also shows files in the directory?

Comment: could you give example output?

Comment: Here is some example output. It only includes the directories, not the files within them:.
    |-power
    |-properties
    |---advanced_battery_charging
    |---peakshift
    |-rtc
    |---rtc1
    |-----power

Comment: Well I editted that previous comment so many times it stopped letting me change it lol. It's apparently impossible to add line breaks in comments so I replaced them with "\n": Here is some example output. It only includes the directories, not the files within them (and it's apparently impossible to put line breaks in comments, so I put in "\n" at every break: .\n
|-power\n
|-properties\n
|---advanced_battery_charging\n
|---peakshift\n
|-rtc\n
|---rtc1\n
|-----power

Answer (score 89):

That oneliner is pretty cool, I'd recommend using the **tree** util.

```
bash-3.2$ mkdir -p this/is/some/nested/example
bash-3.2$ mkdir -p this/is/another/super/nested/example
bash-3.2$ mkdir -p this/is/yet/another/example
bash-3.2$ mkdir -p this/is/some/nested/other/example
bash-3.2$ tree this
this
`-- is
    |-- another
    |   `-- super
    |       `-- nested
    |           `-- example
    |-- some
    |   `-- nested
    |       |-- example
    |       `-- other
    |           `-- example
    `-- yet
        `-- another
            `-- example

13 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: For those on a Mac, `brew install tree`

Comment: I struggled with tree using special characters as default, but suggestion from http://www.codealpha.net/696/putty-and-tree-how-to-avoid-weird-characters-squares/ is to use `tree --charset=ASCII`, so that tree produces chars as in user1116793's example above.

Comment: It has some creative uses too. I use it to visualize my errands (most tools don't have true hierarchical capability - not even Jira).

Answer (score 20):

I realize this question was answered ages ago, but I just found this program called [tree](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/) which is pretty cool too.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. It supports dircolors, and the output is more nicely laid out. It's even a macport too for Mac OS X users.

Comment: `tree` can also be installed using Homebrew, for those who've moved on from Macports.

Comment: It should be noted that, for Windows, you can simply type `tree` from the command line. No need to install anything.

Answer (score 16):

See the [`RecursiveTreeIterator`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivetreeiterator.php) class

> Allows iterating over a RecursiveIterator to generate an ASCII graphic tree.

```
$treeIterator = new RecursiveTreeIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/path/to/dir'),
    RecursiveTreeIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($treeIterator as $val) echo $val, PHP_EOL;
```

Output will be something like this (with c:\php on my machine):

```
|-c:\php5\cfg
|-c:\php5\data
| |-c:\php5\data\Base
| | \-c:\php5\data\Base\design
| |   |-c:\php5\data\Base\design\class_diagram.png
| |   \-c:\php5\data\Base\design\design.txt
| |-c:\php5\data\ConsoleTools
| | \-c:\php5\data\ConsoleTools\design
| |   |-c:\php5\data\ConsoleTools\design\class_diagram.png
| |   |-c:\php5\data\ConsoleTools\design\console.png
| |   |-c:\php5\data\ConsoleTools\design\console.xml
…
```

Answer (score 14):

[exa with --tree](https://the.exa.website/) does an excellent job:

```
exa --tree ~/tmp/public/

<dir>
├── aboutme
│  └── index.html
├── atrecurse
│  └── index.html
├── base.css
├── html5
│  ├── cat-and-mouse
│  └── frantic
│     ├── css
│     │  └── main.css
```

Comment: Found this late but this is awesome! Developing a tool for generating the file tree for a certain type of project and `exa -T -D` has been really really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Not a library per se, but this little utility is handy for generating quick tree graphs without leaving the browser: https://tree.nathanfriend.io/

Disclaimer: I'm the author :).

Comment: the best answer

Comment: This is really nice! bookmarked

Answer (score 1):

Cool Python script to do it: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/217212/

Answer (score 1):

[php ]To tweak the tree symbols, taken from https://gist.github.com/hakre/3599532

```
<?php
$path = './targetdir';
$unicodeTreePrefix = function(RecursiveTreeIterator $tree){
  $prefixParts = [
      RecursiveTreeIterator::PREFIX_LEFT         => ' ',
      RecursiveTreeIterator::PREFIX_MID_HAS_NEXT => '+ ',
      RecursiveTreeIterator::PREFIX_END_HAS_NEXT => '├ ',
      RecursiveTreeIterator::PREFIX_END_LAST     => '└ '
    ];
  foreach ($prefixParts as $part => $string) {
      $tree->setPrefixPart($part, $string);
  }
};
$dir  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME | RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$tree = new RecursiveTreeIterator($dir);
$unicodeTreePrefix($tree);
echo "<br><br>";
echo "[$path]<br>";
foreach ($tree as $filename => $line) {
  echo $tree->getPrefix(), $filename, "<br>";
}
```

Example output

```html
[./targetdir]<br> ├ aHR0cHM<br> ├ gtyyu.txt<br> ├ Screenshot at 2020-05-28 22-23-30.png<br> ├ 2004 - Synchrone<br> + ├ 09-Live for willyman.mp3<br> + ├ 04-Inabox.mp3<br> + ├ 05-Trashastan.mp3<br> + ├ 07-Nordick.mp3<br> + ├ 08-Rupture.mp3<br> + ├ Best of<br> + + ├ 08 - Civil War.mp3<br> + + ├ 09 - 14 Years.mp3<br> + + ├ 05 - Welcome To The Jungle.mp3<br> + + ├ 06 - Don't Cry.mp3<br> + + ├ 04 - Sweet Child O' Mine.mp3<br> + + ├ 02 - Paradise City.mp3<br> + + ├ 07 - Yesterdays.mp3<br> + + ├ 03 - Patience.mp3<br> + + ├ 01 - November Rain.mp3<br> + + └ 10 - Estranged.mp3<br> + ├ 03-Sarangui.mp3<br> + ├ 06-The test.mp3<br> + ├ 01-Sabradub.mp3<br> + └ 02-L'uzure.mp3<br> ├ Screenshot at 2020-02-11 12-31-52.png<br> ├ trur.txt<br> ├ .hidden<br> + ├ .sub_article.txt<br> + └ sub_article_in_hidden.txt<br> ├ gtuitre.txt<br> ├ aHR0cHM.txt<br> ├ CREEP.mp3<br> ├ subfolder<br> + └ sub_article.txt<br> ├ filtle.txt<br> ├ Best of<br> + ├ 08 - Civil War.mp3<br> + ├ 09 - 14 Years.mp3<br> + ├ 05 - Welcome To The Jungle.mp3<br> + ├ 06 - Don't Cry.mp3<br> + ├ 04 - Sweet Child O' Mine.mp3<br> + ├ 02 - Paradise City.mp3<br> + ├ 07 - Yesterdays.mp3<br> + ├ 03 - Patience.mp3<br> + ├ 01 - November Rain.mp3<br> + └ 10 - Estranged.mp3<br> ├ Screenshot at 2020-05-12 14-51-56.png<br> ├ of.txt<br> ├ highlight.css<br> └ Screenshot at 2020-06-10 19-28-51.png<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

This has moved on a lot in recent years. The linux version in the package managers is cleaner and colorized:

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install tree
```

CentOS/RHEL/OpenSUSE:

```
sudo yum install tree
```

If you have a massive subdirectory of your `current_directory` structure and only want to show a sample of what the structure contains you can do something like:

```
tree -P *my_own_pattern_to_find* current_directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [App::Asciio](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-Asciio/)