# How to print binary tree diagram in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, printing, binary-tree

How can I print a binary tree in Java so that the output is like:

```
   4 
  / \ 
 2   5
```

My node:

```
public class Node<A extends Comparable> {
    Node<A> left, right;
    A data;

    public Node(A data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 278, accepted):

I've created simple binary tree printer. You can use and modify it as you want, but it's not optimized anyway. I think that a lot of things can be improved here ;)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class BTreePrinterTest {

    private static Node<Integer> test1() {
        Node<Integer> root = new Node<Integer>(2);
        Node<Integer> n11 = new Node<Integer>(7);
        Node<Integer> n12 = new Node<Integer>(5);
        Node<Integer> n21 = new Node<Integer>(2);
        Node<Integer> n22 = new Node<Integer>(6);
        Node<Integer> n23 = new Node<Integer>(3);
        Node<Integer> n24 = new Node<Integer>(6);
        Node<Integer> n31 = new Node<Integer>(5);
        Node<Integer> n32 = new Node<Integer>(8);
        Node<Integer> n33 = new Node<Integer>(4);
        Node<Integer> n34 = new Node<Integer>(5);
        Node<Integer> n35 = new Node<Integer>(8);
        Node<Integer> n36 = new Node<Integer>(4);
        Node<Integer> n37 = new Node<Integer>(5);
        Node<Integer> n38 = new Node<Integer>(8);

        root.left = n11;
        root.right = n12;

        n11.left = n21;
        n11.right = n22;
        n12.left = n23;
        n12.right = n24;

        n21.left = n31;
        n21.right = n32;
        n22.left = n33;
        n22.right = n34;
        n23.left = n35;
        n23.right = n36;
        n24.left = n37;
        n24.right = n38;

        return root;
    }

    private static Node<Integer> test2() {
        Node<Integer> root = new Node<Integer>(2);
        Node<Integer> n11 = new Node<Integer>(7);
        Node<Integer> n12 = new Node<Integer>(5);
        Node<Integer> n21 = new Node<Integer>(2);
        Node<Integer> n22 = new Node<Integer>(6);
        Node<Integer> n23 = new Node<Integer>(9);
        Node<Integer> n31 = new Node<Integer>(5);
        Node<Integer> n32 = new Node<Integer>(8);
        Node<Integer> n33 = new Node<Integer>(4);

        root.left = n11;
        root.right = n12;

        n11.left = n21;
        n11.right = n22;

        n12.right = n23;
        n22.left = n31;
        n22.right = n32;

        n23.left = n33;

        return root;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BTreePrinter.printNode(test1());
        BTreePrinter.printNode(test2());

    }
}

class Node<T extends Comparable<?>> {
    Node<T> left, right;
    T data;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class BTreePrinter {

    public static <T extends Comparable<?>> void printNode(Node<T> root) {
        int maxLevel = BTreePrinter.maxLevel(root);

        printNodeInternal(Collections.singletonList(root), 1, maxLevel);
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<?>> void printNodeInternal(List<Node<T>> nodes, int level, int maxLevel) {
        if (nodes.isEmpty() || BTreePrinter.isAllElementsNull(nodes))
            return;

        int floor = maxLevel - level;
        int endgeLines = (int) Math.pow(2, (Math.max(floor - 1, 0)));
        int firstSpaces = (int) Math.pow(2, (floor)) - 1;
        int betweenSpaces = (int) Math.pow(2, (floor + 1)) - 1;

        BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(firstSpaces);

        List<Node<T>> newNodes = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
        for (Node<T> node : nodes) {
            if (node != null) {
                System.out.print(node.data);
                newNodes.add(node.left);
                newNodes.add(node.right);
            } else {
                newNodes.add(null);
                newNodes.add(null);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(betweenSpaces);
        }
        System.out.println("");

        for (int i = 1; i <= endgeLines; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
                BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(firstSpaces - i);
                if (nodes.get(j) == null) {
                    BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(endgeLines + endgeLines + i + 1);
                    continue;
                }

                if (nodes.get(j).left != null)
                    System.out.print("/");
                else
                    BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(1);

                BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(i + i - 1);

                if (nodes.get(j).right != null)
                    System.out.print("\\");
                else
                    BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(1);

                BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(endgeLines + endgeLines - i);
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }

        printNodeInternal(newNodes, level + 1, maxLevel);
    }

    private static void printWhitespaces(int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            System.out.print(" ");
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<?>> int maxLevel(Node<T> node) {
        if (node == null)
            return 0;

        return Math.max(BTreePrinter.maxLevel(node.left), BTreePrinter.maxLevel(node.right)) + 1;
    }

    private static <T> boolean isAllElementsNull(List<T> list) {
        for (Object object : list) {
            if (object != null)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Output 1 :

```
         2               
        / \       
       /   \      
      /     \     
     /       \    
     7       5       
    / \     / \   
   /   \   /   \  
   2   6   3   6   
  / \ / \ / \ / \ 
  5 8 4 5 8 4 5 8
```

Output 2 :

```
       2               
      / \       
     /   \      
    /     \     
   /       \    
   7       5       
  / \       \   
 /   \       \  
 2   6       9   
    / \     /   
    5 8     4
```

Comment: how to convert this output to horizontal?

Comment: For horizontal output is better to use Vasya Novikov's solution.

Comment: It will be great if you can elaborate on choosing 2^n - 1 as first spaces and 2^(n+1) - 1 as the between spaces

Comment: It is good for balanced trees as I tried it for one of the right-skewed trees of 15 values and it became very unmanageable to see the print.

Comment: This works OK if the nodes are 1 digit or at least equally wide, but it breaks for warying sizes. See my answer for a better version of this.

Comment: My tree is 44 layers deep, so java crashes when trying to print 8796093022207 whitespaces. So be warned.

Answer (score 341):

Print a [large] tree by lines.

output example:

```
z
├── c
│   ├── a
│   └── b
├── d
├── e
│   └── asdf
└── f
```

code:

```
public class TreeNode {

    final String name;
    final List<TreeNode> children;

    public TreeNode(String name, List<TreeNode> children) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(50);
        print(buffer, "", "");
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    private void print(StringBuilder buffer, String prefix, String childrenPrefix) {
        buffer.append(prefix);
        buffer.append(name);
        buffer.append('\n');
        for (Iterator<TreeNode> it = children.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            TreeNode next = it.next();
            if (it.hasNext()) {
                next.print(buffer, childrenPrefix + "├── ", childrenPrefix + "│   ");
            } else {
                next.print(buffer, childrenPrefix + "└── ", childrenPrefix + "    ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. This answer doesn't exactly focus on "binary" trees -- instead, it prints all kinds of trees. Solution is inspired by the "tree" command in linux.

Comment: Does this solution handle right skewed binary trees?

Comment: @VasyaNovikov how would you rewrite `children.get(children.size() - 1)` if HashMap was used for children? I managed to modify every other part but this one.

Comment: @LeNguyenDuyAnh what's the HashMap proposed type signature though? `HashMap<String, List<String>>` ?

Comment: I have implemented my tree as `HashMap<String, Node>`. String is the Node's id.

Comment: I actually implemented something similar in a small Java library called [text-tree](https://gitlab.com/barfuin/text-tree). Maybe it helps someone.

Comment: For me it prints ??? instead of "├── " and "└── "

Answer (score 76):

I've made an improved algorithm for this, which handles nicely nodes with different size. It prints top-down using lines.

```
package alg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Binary tree printer
 * 
 * @author MightyPork
 */
public class TreePrinter
{
    /** Node that can be printed */
    public interface PrintableNode
    {
        /** Get left child */
        PrintableNode getLeft();


        /** Get right child */
        PrintableNode getRight();


        /** Get text to be printed */
        String getText();
    }


    /**
     * Print a tree
     * 
     * @param root
     *            tree root node
     */
    public static void print(PrintableNode root)
    {
        List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        List<PrintableNode> level = new ArrayList<PrintableNode>();
        List<PrintableNode> next = new ArrayList<PrintableNode>();

        level.add(root);
        int nn = 1;

        int widest = 0;

        while (nn != 0) {
            List<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();

            nn = 0;

            for (PrintableNode n : level) {
                if (n == null) {
                    line.add(null);

                    next.add(null);
                    next.add(null);
                } else {
                    String aa = n.getText();
                    line.add(aa);
                    if (aa.length() > widest) widest = aa.length();

                    next.add(n.getLeft());
                    next.add(n.getRight());

                    if (n.getLeft() != null) nn++;
                    if (n.getRight() != null) nn++;
                }
            }

            if (widest % 2 == 1) widest++;

            lines.add(line);

            List<PrintableNode> tmp = level;
            level = next;
            next = tmp;
            next.clear();
        }

        int perpiece = lines.get(lines.size() - 1).size() * (widest + 4);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            List<String> line = lines.get(i);
            int hpw = (int) Math.floor(perpiece / 2f) - 1;

            if (i > 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < line.size(); j++) {

                    // split node
                    char c = ' ';
                    if (j % 2 == 1) {
                        if (line.get(j - 1) != null) {
                            c = (line.get(j) != null) ? '┴' : '┘';
                        } else {
                            if (j < line.size() && line.get(j) != null) c = '└';
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print(c);

                    // lines and spaces
                    if (line.get(j) == null) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < perpiece - 1; k++) {
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                    } else {

                        for (int k = 0; k < hpw; k++) {
                            System.out.print(j % 2 == 0 ? " " : "─");
                        }
                        System.out.print(j % 2 == 0 ? "┌" : "┐");
                        for (int k = 0; k < hpw; k++) {
                            System.out.print(j % 2 == 0 ? "─" : " ");
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            // print line of numbers
            for (int j = 0; j < line.size(); j++) {

                String f = line.get(j);
                if (f == null) f = "";
                int gap1 = (int) Math.ceil(perpiece / 2f - f.length() / 2f);
                int gap2 = (int) Math.floor(perpiece / 2f - f.length() / 2f);

                // a number
                for (int k = 0; k < gap1; k++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print(f);
                for (int k = 0; k < gap2; k++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();

            perpiece /= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

To use this for your Tree, let your `Node` class implement `PrintableNode`.

Example output:

```
                                         2952:0                                             
                    ┌───────────────────────┴───────────────────────┐                       
                 1249:-1                                         5866:0                     
        ┌───────────┴───────────┐                       ┌───────────┴───────────┐           
     491:-1                  1572:0                  4786:1                  6190:0         
  ┌─────┘                                               └─────┐           ┌─────┴─────┐     
339:0                                                      5717:0      6061:0      6271:0
```

Comment: I was trying to replicate the "selected answer" technique.
But I think this one of the best answers here. So Robust and concise.

Comment: After implementing this it appears to work great, but only for balanced trees. Anything imbalanced returns odd results.

Comment: I get `???????????` instead of the lines between nodes but should be just some UTF8 ans stuff problem. Anyway, great stuff, I have to say. Best answer for me as it is really easy to use.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Just had to change all the special characters of your _lines and spaces_ paragraph.

Comment: Nice, to support printing an array of elements, created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/rahulsh1/48dc557c76b3fe5609ae4445d5284210) which just does that using @MightyPork logic for printing the tree. See `public static <T> void print(T[] elems)`

Comment: Best answer so far. Even better then accepted answer. Really nice.

Comment: I like the interface approach but there is no need to provide a getText() method here. Better to use toString() instead and expect the implementor to provide a good impl for that.

Comment: This is most robust and precise answer

Comment: What are the numbers with `:`?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar it's just some data i was visualising

Comment: Great idea to put an abstraction ! It is easier to use

Comment: Gives me a heap space error :(

Answer (score 45):

```
public static class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    T value;
    Node<T> left, right;

    public void insertToTree(T v) {
        if (value == null) {
            value = v;
            return;
        }
        if (v.compareTo(value) < 0) {
            if (left == null) {
                left = new Node<T>();
            }
            left.insertToTree(v);
        } else {
            if (right == null) {
                right = new Node<T>();
            }
            right.insertToTree(v);
        }
    }

    public void printTree(OutputStreamWriter out) throws IOException {
        if (right != null) {
            right.printTree(out, true, "");
        }
        printNodeValue(out);
        if (left != null) {
            left.printTree(out, false, "");
        }
    }
    private void printNodeValue(OutputStreamWriter out) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            out.write("<null>");
        } else {
            out.write(value.toString());
        }
        out.write('\n');
    }
    // use string and not stringbuffer on purpose as we need to change the indent at each recursion
    private void printTree(OutputStreamWriter out, boolean isRight, String indent) throws IOException {
        if (right != null) {
            right.printTree(out, true, indent + (isRight ? "        " : " |      "));
        }
        out.write(indent);
        if (isRight) {
            out.write(" /");
        } else {
            out.write(" \\");
        }
        out.write("----- ");
        printNodeValue(out);
        if (left != null) {
            left.printTree(out, false, indent + (isRight ? " |      " : "        "));
        }
    }

}
```

will print:

```
                 /----- 20
                 |       \----- 15
         /----- 14
         |       \----- 13
 /----- 12
 |       |       /----- 11
 |       \----- 10
 |               \----- 9
8
 |               /----- 7
 |       /----- 6
 |       |       \----- 5
 \----- 4
         |       /----- 3
         \----- 2
                 \----- 1
```

for the input

8
4
12
2
6
10
14
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
20
15

this is a variant from @anurag's answer - it was bugging me to see the extra |s

Comment: It'd be awesome if you could rotate it 90°.

Answer (score 45):

Adapted from [Vasya Novikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1091436/vasya-novikov)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8948691/567390) to make it more *binary*, and use a `StringBuilder` for efficiency (concatenating `String` objects together in Java is generally inefficient).

```
public StringBuilder toString(StringBuilder prefix, boolean isTail, StringBuilder sb) {
    if(right!=null) {
        right.toString(new StringBuilder().append(prefix).append(isTail ? "│   " : "    "), false, sb);
    }
    sb.append(prefix).append(isTail ? "└── " : "┌── ").append(value.toString()).append("\n");
    if(left!=null) {
        left.toString(new StringBuilder().append(prefix).append(isTail ? "    " : "│   "), true, sb);
    }
    return sb;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.toString(new StringBuilder(), true, new StringBuilder()).toString();
}
```

Output:

```
│       ┌── 7
│   ┌── 6
│   │   └── 5
└── 4
    │   ┌── 3
    └── 2
        └── 1
            └── 0
```

Comment: It does not work for a tree when we insert values: 30,40,50,60,70,80 into a BST. As that creates a right-skewed tree. The value for isTail should be false when `right != null`.I did the edit and tested it, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I just edited the answer, it that better?

Comment: Thank you, @Vasya Novikov's answer is great but I need a linklist version of it, and your answer just fit my case.

Comment: In all of the answers, this produces the best looking tree, and the code is very clean!

Comment: Very nice and elegant solution!

Answer (score 28):

I found VasyaNovikov's answer very useful for printing a large general tree, and modified it for a binary tree

Code:

```
class TreeNode {
    Integer data = null;
    TreeNode left = null;
    TreeNode right = null;

    TreeNode(Integer data) {this.data = data;}

    public void print() {
        print("", this, false);
    }

    public void print(String prefix, TreeNode n, boolean isLeft) {
        if (n != null) {
            System.out.println (prefix + (isLeft ? "|-- " : "\\-- ") + n.data);
            print(prefix + (isLeft ? "|   " : "    "), n.left, true);
            print(prefix + (isLeft ? "|   " : "    "), n.right, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
\-- 7
    |-- 3
    |   |-- 1
    |   |   \-- 2
    |   \-- 5
    |       |-- 4
    |       \-- 6
    \-- 11
        |-- 9
        |   |-- 8
        |   \-- 10
        \-- 13
            |-- 12
            \-- 14
```

Answer (score 20):

michal.kreuzman nice one I will have to say. It was useful.

However, the above works only for single digits: if you are going to use more than one digit, the structure is going to get misplaced since you are using spaces and not tabs.

As for my later codes I needed more digits than only 2, so I made a program myself.

It has some bugs now, again right now I am feeling lazy to correct them but it prints very beautifully and the nodes can take a larger number of digits.

The tree is not going to be as the question mentions but it is 270 degrees rotated :)

```
public static void printBinaryTree(TreeNode root, int level){
    if(root==null)
         return;
    printBinaryTree(root.right, level+1);
    if(level!=0){
        for(int i=0;i<level-1;i++)
            System.out.print("|\t");
        System.out.println("|-------"+root.val);
    }
    else
        System.out.println(root.val);
    printBinaryTree(root.left, level+1);
}
```

Place this function with your own specified TreeNode and keep the level initially 0, and enjoy!

Here are some of the sample outputs:

```
|       |       |-------11
|       |-------10
|       |       |-------9
|-------8
|       |       |-------7
|       |-------6
|       |       |-------5
4
|       |-------3
|-------2
|       |-------1


|       |       |       |-------10
|       |       |-------9
|       |-------8
|       |       |-------7
|-------6
|       |-------5
4
|       |-------3
|-------2
|       |-------1
```

Only problem is with the extending branches; I will try to solve the problem as soon as possible but till then you can use it too.

Answer (score 17):

Your tree will need twice the distance for each layer:

```
       a
      / \
     /   \
    /     \
   /       \
   b       c
  / \     / \
 /   \   /   \
 d   e   f   g
/ \ / \ / \ / \
h i j k l m n o
```

You can save your tree in an array of arrays, one array for every depth:

```
[[a],[b,c],[d,e,f,g],[h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o]]
```

If your tree is not full, you need to include empty values in that array:

```
       a
      / \
     /   \
    /     \
   /       \
   b       c
  / \     / \
 /   \   /   \
 d   e   f   g
/ \   \ / \   \
h i   k l m   o
[[a],[b,c],[d,e,f,g],[h,i, ,k,l,m, ,o]]
```

Then you can iterate over the array to print your tree, printing spaces before the first element and between the elements depending on the depth and printing the lines depending on if the corresponding elements in the array for the next layer are filled or not.
If your values can be more than one character long, you need to find the longest value while creating the array representation and multiply all widths and the number of lines accordingly.

Comment: What if the tree isn't complete?  In that case it seems like you should be able to do this without doubling the space at each level.

Comment: Yes, but only in some very limited cases where most subtrees are linked lists instead of trees from the same level downward or you would draw different subtrees with different spacing between the layers...

Answer (score 6):

Based on VasyaNovikov answer. Improved with some Java magic: Generics and Functional interface.

```
/**
 * Print a tree structure in a pretty ASCII fromat.
 * @param prefix Currnet previx. Use "" in initial call!
 * @param node The current node. Pass the root node of your tree in initial call.
 * @param getChildrenFunc A {@link Function} that returns the children of a given node.
 * @param isTail Is node the last of its sibblings. Use true in initial call. (This is needed for pretty printing.)
 * @param <T> The type of your nodes. Anything that has a toString can be used.
 */
private <T> void printTreeRec(String prefix, T node, Function<T, List<T>> getChildrenFunc, boolean isTail) {
    String nodeName = node.toString();
    String nodeConnection = isTail ? "└── " : "├── ";
    log.debug(prefix + nodeConnection + nodeName);
    List<T> children = getChildrenFunc.apply(node);
    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
        String newPrefix = prefix + (isTail ? "    " : "│   ");
        printTreeRec(newPrefix, children.get(i), getChildrenFunc, i == children.size()-1);
    }
}
```

Example initial call:

```
Function<ChecksumModel, List<ChecksumModel>> getChildrenFunc = node -> getChildrenOf(node)
printTreeRec("", rootNode, getChildrenFunc, true);
```

Will output something like

```
└── rootNode
    ├── childNode1
    ├── childNode2
    │   ├── childNode2.1
    │   ├── childNode2.2
    │   └── childNode2.3
    ├── childNode3
    └── childNode4
```

Comment: took 10 seconds to use it! Great job!

Answer (score 3):

```
public void printPreety() {
    List<TreeNode> list = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
    list.add(head);
    printTree(list, getHeight(head));
}

public int getHeight(TreeNode head) {

    if (head == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + Math.max(getHeight(head.left), getHeight(head.right));
    }
}

/**
 * pass head node in list and height of the tree 
 * 
 * @param levelNodes
 * @param level
 */
private void printTree(List<TreeNode> levelNodes, int level) {

    List<TreeNode> nodes = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();

    //indentation for first node in given level
    printIndentForLevel(level);

    for (TreeNode treeNode : levelNodes) {

        //print node data
        System.out.print(treeNode == null?" ":treeNode.data);

        //spacing between nodes
        printSpacingBetweenNodes(level);

        //if its not a leaf node
        if(level>1){
            nodes.add(treeNode == null? null:treeNode.left);
            nodes.add(treeNode == null? null:treeNode.right);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

    if(level>1){        
        printTree(nodes, level-1);
    }
}

private void printIndentForLevel(int level){
    for (int i = (int) (Math.pow(2,level-1)); i >0; i--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}

private void printSpacingBetweenNodes(int level){
    //spacing between nodes
    for (int i = (int) ((Math.pow(2,level-1))*2)-1; i >0; i--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}


Prints Tree in following format:
                4                               
        3               7               
    1               5       8       
      2                       10   
                             9
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private StringBuilder prettyPrint(Node root, int currentHeight, int totalHeight) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int spaces = getSpaceCount(totalHeight-currentHeight + 1);
        if(root == null) {
            //create a 'spatial' block and return it
            String row = String.format("%"+(2*spaces+1)+"s%n", "");
            //now repeat this row space+1 times
            String block = new String(new char[spaces+1]).replace("\0", row);
            return new StringBuilder(block);
        }
        if(currentHeight==totalHeight) return new StringBuilder(root.data+"");
        int slashes = getSlashCount(totalHeight-currentHeight +1);
        sb.append(String.format("%"+(spaces+1)+"s%"+spaces+"s", root.data+"", ""));
        sb.append("\n");
        //now print / and \
        // but make sure that left and right exists
        char leftSlash = root.left == null? ' ':'/';
        char rightSlash = root.right==null? ' ':'\\';
        int spaceInBetween = 1;
        for(int i=0, space = spaces-1; i<slashes; i++, space --, spaceInBetween+=2) {
            for(int j=0; j<space; j++) sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(leftSlash);
            for(int j=0; j<spaceInBetween; j++) sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(rightSlash+"");
            for(int j=0; j<space; j++) sb.append(" ");
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        //sb.append("\n");

        //now get string representations of left and right subtrees
        StringBuilder leftTree = prettyPrint(root.left, currentHeight+1, totalHeight);
        StringBuilder rightTree = prettyPrint(root.right, currentHeight+1, totalHeight);
        // now line by line print the trees side by side
        Scanner leftScanner = new Scanner(leftTree.toString());
        Scanner rightScanner = new Scanner(rightTree.toString());
//      spaceInBetween+=1;
        while(leftScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            if(currentHeight==totalHeight-1) {
                sb.append(String.format("%-2s %2s", leftScanner.nextLine(), rightScanner.nextLine()));
                sb.append("\n");
                spaceInBetween-=2;              
            }
            else {
                sb.append(leftScanner.nextLine());
                sb.append(" ");
                sb.append(rightScanner.nextLine()+"\n");
            }
        }

        return sb;

    }
private int getSpaceCount(int height) {
        return (int) (3*Math.pow(2, height-2)-1);
    }
private int getSlashCount(int height) {
        if(height <= 3) return height -1;
        return (int) (3*Math.pow(2, height-3)-1);
    }
```

https://github.com/murtraja/java-binary-tree-printer

only works for 1 to 2 digit integers (i was lazy to make it generic)

[image: skewed]
[image: full]

Answer (score 3):

This was the simplest solution for horizontal view. Tried with bunch of examples. Works well for my purpose. Updated from @nitin-k 's answer.

```
public void print(String prefix, BTNode n, boolean isLeft) {
    if (n != null) {
        print(prefix + "     ", n.right, false);
        System.out.println (prefix + ("|-- ") + n.data);
        print(prefix + "     ", n.left, true);
    }
}
```

Call:

```
bst.print("", bst.root, false);
```

Solution:

```
                         |-- 80
                    |-- 70
               |-- 60
          |-- 50
     |-- 40
|-- 30
     |-- 20
          |-- 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a class (± 60 lines) that can produce a string like this:

```
       330
 ┌──────┴──────┐
101          1738
 └─┐        ┌──┴──┐
  198      467  1922
 ┌─┘        └─┐   └─┐
154          648  1924
 └─┐    ┌─────┴──────┐
  155  621         1524
      ┌─┘       ┌────┴─────┐
     576       987       1531
      └─┐    ┌──┴──┐     ┌─┘
       617  703  1079  1527
                 ┌─┘
               1066
```

The code assumes a `Node` class with `left`, `right` and `data` fields. If for instance you have a `Node root`, the below `TreeFormatter` can be used as follows:

```
    TreeFormatter formatter = new TreeFormatter();
    System.out.println(formatter.topDown(root));
```

The class itself:

```
class TreeFormatter {
    int padding = 2; // minimum number of horizontal spaces between two node data

    private int indent(List<String> lines, int margin) {
        // If negative, prefix all lines with spaces and return 0
        if (margin >= 0) return margin;
        String spaces = " ".repeat(-margin);
        int i = 0;
        for (var line : lines) {
            lines.set(i++, spaces + line);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    
    private List<String> merge(List<String> left, List<String> right) {
        // Merge two arrays, where the right strings are indented so there is no overlap
        int minSize = Math.min(left.size(), right.size());
        int offset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < minSize; i++) {
            offset = Math.max(offset, left.get(i).length() + padding - right.get(i).replaceAll("\\S.*", "").length());
        }
        indent(right, -indent(left, offset));
        for (int i = 0; i < minSize; i++) {
            left.set(i, left.get(i) + right.get(i).substring(left.get(i).length()));
        }
        if (right.size() > minSize) {
            left.addAll(right.subList(minSize, right.size()));
        }
        return left;
    }

    private List<String> buildLines(Node node) {
        if (node == null) return new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> lines = merge(buildLines(node.left), buildLines(node.right));
        int half = String.valueOf(node.data).length() / 2;
        int i = half;
        if (lines.size() > 0) {
            String line;
            i = lines.get(0).indexOf("*"); // Find index of first subtree
            if (node.right == null) {
                line = " ".repeat(i) + "┌─┘";
                i += 2;
            } else if (node.left == null) {
                line = " ".repeat(i = indent(lines, i - 2)) + "└─┐";
            } else {
                int dist = lines.get(0).length() - 1 - i; // Find distance between subtree roots
                line = String.format("%s┌%s┴%s┐", " ".repeat(i), "─".repeat(dist / 2 - 1), "─".repeat((dist - 1) / 2));
                i += dist / 2;
            }
            lines.set(0, line);
        }
        lines.add(0, " ".repeat(indent(lines, i - half)) + node.data);
        lines.add(0, " ".repeat(i + Math.max(0, half - i)) + "*"); // Add a marker for caller
        return lines;
    }
    
    public String topDown(Node root) {
        List<String> lines = buildLines(root);
        return String.join("\n", lines.subList(1, lines.size()));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only working answer +1

Comment: Quite useful. +1

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple solution to print out a tree.  It is not that pretty, but it is really simple:

```
enum { kWidth = 6 };
void PrintSpace(int n)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    printf(" ");
}

void PrintTree(struct Node * root, int level)
{
  if (!root) return;
  PrintTree(root->right, level + 1);
  PrintSpace(level * kWidth);
  printf("%d", root->data);
  PrintTree(root->left, level + 1);
}
```

Sample output:

```
      106
            105
104
            103
                  102
                        101
      100
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to print a binary tree in one of my projects, for that I have prepared a java class `TreePrinter`, one of the sample output is:

```
                [+]
               /   \
              /     \
             /       \
            /         \
           /           \
        [*]             \
       /   \             [-]
[speed]     [2]         /   \
                    [45]     [12]
```

Here is the code for class `TreePrinter` along with class `TextNode`. For printing any tree you can just create an equivalent tree with `TextNode` class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TreePrinter {

    public TreePrinter(){
    }

    public static String TreeString(TextNode root){
        ArrayList layers = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList bottom = new ArrayList();

        FillBottom(bottom, root);  DrawEdges(root);

        int height = GetHeight(root);
        for(int i = 0; i  s.length()) min = s.length();

            if(!n.isEdge) s += "[";
            s += n.text;
            if(!n.isEdge) s += "]";

            layers.set(n.depth, s);
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i  temp = new ArrayList();

            for(int i = 0; i  0) temp.get(i-1).left = x;
                temp.add(x);
            }

            temp.get(count-1).left = n.left;
            n.left.depth = temp.get(count-1).depth+1;
            n.left = temp.get(0);

            DrawEdges(temp.get(count-1).left);
        }
        if(n.right != null){
            int count = n.right.x - (n.x + n.text.length() + 2);
            ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();

            for(int i = 0; i  0) temp.get(i-1).right = x;
                temp.add(x);
            }

            temp.get(count-1).right = n.right;
            n.right.depth = temp.get(count-1).depth+1;
            n.right = temp.get(0);  

            DrawEdges(temp.get(count-1).right);
        }
    }

    private static void FillBottom(ArrayList bottom, TextNode n){
        if(n == null) return;

        FillBottom(bottom, n.left);

        if(!bottom.isEmpty()){            
            int i = bottom.size()-1;
            while(bottom.get(i).isEdge) i--;
            TextNode last = bottom.get(i);

            if(!n.isEdge) n.x = last.x + last.text.length() + 3;
        }
        bottom.add(n);
        FillBottom(bottom, n.right);
    }

    private static boolean isLeaf(TextNode n){
        return (n.left == null && n.right == null);
    }

    private static int GetHeight(TextNode n){
        if(n == null) return 0;

        int l = GetHeight(n.left);
        int r = GetHeight(n.right);

        return Math.max(l, r) + 1;
    }
}


class TextNode {
    public String text;
    public TextNode parent, left, right;
    public boolean isEdge;
    public int x, depth;

    public TextNode(String text){
        this.text = text;
        parent = null; left = null; right = null;
        isEdge = false;
        x = 0; depth = 0;
    }
}
```

Finally here is a test class for printing given sample:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TextNode root = new TextNode("+");
        root.left = new TextNode("*");            root.left.parent = root;
        root.right = new TextNode("-");           root.right.parent = root;
        root.left.left = new TextNode("speed");   root.left.left.parent = root.left;
        root.left.right = new TextNode("2");      root.left.right.parent = root.left;
        root.right.left = new TextNode("45");     root.right.left.parent = root.right;
        root.right.right = new TextNode("12");    root.right.right.parent = root.right;

        System.out.println(TreePrinter.TreeString(root));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/AharonSambol/PrettyPrintTreeJava

I know I'm late.. But I made this solution which works not only for simple trees but also for more complex ones (such as multi-lined strings)

Example output:

[image: example output]

Comment: BTW I made a Python version too: https://github.com/AharonSambol/PrettyPrintTree

Answer (score 0):

Print in Console:

```
                                                500
                       700                                             300   
    200                                   400
```

Simple code :

```
public int getHeight()
    {
        if(rootNode == null) return -1;
        return getHeight(rootNode);
    }

    private int getHeight(Node node)
    {
        if(node == null) return -1;

        return Math.max(getHeight(node.left), getHeight(node.right)) + 1;
    }

    public void printBinaryTree(Node rootNode)
    {
        Queue<Node> rootsQueue = new LinkedList<Node>();
        Queue<Node> levelQueue = new LinkedList<Node>();
        levelQueue.add(rootNode);
        int treeHeight = getHeight();
        int firstNodeGap;
        int internalNodeGap;
        int copyinternalNodeGap;
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            internalNodeGap = (int)(Math.pow(2, treeHeight + 1) -1);  
            copyinternalNodeGap = internalNodeGap;
            firstNodeGap = internalNodeGap/2;

            boolean levelFirstNode = true;

            while(!levelQueue.isEmpty())
            {
                internalNodeGap = copyinternalNodeGap;
                Node currNode = levelQueue.poll();
                if(currNode != null)
                {
                    if(levelFirstNode)
                    {
                        while(firstNodeGap > 0)
                        {
                            System.out.format("%s", "   ");
                            firstNodeGap--; 
                        }
                        levelFirstNode =false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while(internalNodeGap>0)
                        {
                            internalNodeGap--;
                            System.out.format("%s", "   ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.format("%3d",currNode.data);
                    rootsQueue.add(currNode);
                }
            }

            --treeHeight;

            while(!rootsQueue.isEmpty())
            {
                Node currNode = rootsQueue.poll();
                if(currNode != null)
                {
                    levelQueue.add(currNode.left);
                    levelQueue.add(currNode.right);
                }
            }

            if(levelQueue.isEmpty()) break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very versatile tree printer. Not the best looking, but it handles a lot of cases. Feel free to add slashes if you can figure that out.
[image]

```
package com.tomac120.NodePrinter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by elijah on 6/28/16.
 */
public class NodePrinter{
    final private List<List<PrintableNodePosition>> nodesByRow;
    int maxColumnsLeft = 0;
    int maxColumnsRight = 0;
    int maxTitleLength = 0;
    String sep = " ";
    int depth = 0;

    public NodePrinter(PrintableNode rootNode, int chars_per_node){
        this.setDepth(rootNode,1);
        nodesByRow = new ArrayList<>(depth);
        this.addNode(rootNode._getPrintableNodeInfo(),0,0);
        for (int i = 0;i<chars_per_node;i++){
            //sep += " ";
        }
    }

    private void setDepth(PrintableNode info, int depth){
        if (depth > this.depth){
            this.depth = depth;
        }
        if (info._getLeftChild() != null){
            this.setDepth(info._getLeftChild(),depth+1);
        }
        if (info._getRightChild() != null){
            this.setDepth(info._getRightChild(),depth+1);
        }
    }

    private void addNode(PrintableNodeInfo node, int level, int position){
        if (position < 0 && -position > maxColumnsLeft){
            maxColumnsLeft = -position;
        }
        if (position > 0 && position > maxColumnsRight){
            maxColumnsRight = position;
        }
        if (node.getTitleLength() > maxTitleLength){
           maxTitleLength = node.getTitleLength();
        }
        List<PrintableNodePosition> row = this.getRow(level);
        row.add(new PrintableNodePosition(node, level, position));
        level++;

        int depthToUse = Math.min(depth,6);
        int levelToUse = Math.min(level,6);
        int offset = depthToUse - levelToUse-1;
        offset = (int)(Math.pow(offset,Math.log(depthToUse)*1.4));
        offset = Math.max(offset,3);


        PrintableNodeInfo leftChild = node.getLeftChildInfo();
        PrintableNodeInfo rightChild = node.getRightChildInfo();
        if (leftChild != null){
            this.addNode(leftChild,level,position-offset);
        }
        if (rightChild != null){
            this.addNode(rightChild,level,position+offset);
        }
    }

    private List<PrintableNodePosition> getRow(int row){
        if (row > nodesByRow.size() - 1){
            nodesByRow.add(new LinkedList<>());
        }
        return nodesByRow.get(row);
    }

    public void print(){
        int max_chars = this.maxColumnsLeft+maxColumnsRight+1;
        int level = 0;
        String node_format = "%-"+this.maxTitleLength+"s";
        for (List<PrintableNodePosition> pos_arr : this.nodesByRow){
            String[] chars = this.getCharactersArray(pos_arr,max_chars);
            String line = "";
            int empty_chars = 0;
            for (int i=0;i<chars.length+1;i++){
                String value_i = i < chars.length ? chars[i]:null;
                if (chars.length + 1 == i || value_i != null){
                    if (empty_chars > 0) {
                        System.out.print(String.format("%-" + empty_chars + "s", " "));
                    }
                    if (value_i != null){
                        System.out.print(String.format(node_format,value_i));
                        empty_chars = -1;
                    } else{
                        empty_chars = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    empty_chars++;
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\n");

            int depthToUse = Math.min(6,depth);
            int line_offset = depthToUse - level;
            line_offset *= 0.5;
            line_offset = Math.max(0,line_offset);

            for (int i=0;i<line_offset;i++){
                System.out.println("");
            }


            level++;
        }
    }

    private String[] getCharactersArray(List<PrintableNodePosition> nodes, int max_chars){
        String[] positions = new String[max_chars+1];
        for (PrintableNodePosition a : nodes){
            int pos_i = maxColumnsLeft + a.column;
            String title_i = a.nodeInfo.getTitleFormatted(this.maxTitleLength);
            positions[pos_i] = title_i;
        }
        return positions;
    }
}
```

NodeInfo class

```
package com.tomac120.NodePrinter;

/**
 * Created by elijah on 6/28/16.
 */
public class PrintableNodeInfo {
    public enum CLI_PRINT_COLOR {
        RESET("\u001B[0m"),
        BLACK("\u001B[30m"),
        RED("\u001B[31m"),
        GREEN("\u001B[32m"),
        YELLOW("\u001B[33m"),
        BLUE("\u001B[34m"),
        PURPLE("\u001B[35m"),
        CYAN("\u001B[36m"),
        WHITE("\u001B[37m");

        final String value;
        CLI_PRINT_COLOR(String value){
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }
    private final String title;
    private final PrintableNode leftChild;
    private final PrintableNode rightChild;
    private final CLI_PRINT_COLOR textColor;

    public PrintableNodeInfo(String title, PrintableNode leftChild, PrintableNode rightChild){
        this(title,leftChild,rightChild,CLI_PRINT_COLOR.BLACK);
    }

    public PrintableNodeInfo(String title, PrintableNode leftChild, PrintableNode righthild, CLI_PRINT_COLOR textColor){
        this.title = title;
        this.leftChild = leftChild;
        this.rightChild = righthild;
        this.textColor = textColor;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public CLI_PRINT_COLOR getTextColor(){
        return textColor;
    }

    public String getTitleFormatted(int max_chars){
        return this.textColor+title+CLI_PRINT_COLOR.RESET;
        /*
        String title = this.title.length() > max_chars ? this.title.substring(0,max_chars+1):this.title;
        boolean left = true;
        while(title.length() < max_chars){
            if (left){
                title = " "+title;
            } else {
                title = title + " ";
            }
        }
        return this.textColor+title+CLI_PRINT_COLOR.RESET;*/
    }

    public int getTitleLength(){
        return title.length();
    }

    public PrintableNodeInfo getLeftChildInfo(){
        if (leftChild == null){
            return null;
        }
        return leftChild._getPrintableNodeInfo();
    }

    public PrintableNodeInfo getRightChildInfo(){
        if (rightChild == null){
            return null;
        }
        return rightChild._getPrintableNodeInfo();
    }
}
```

NodePosition class

```
package com.tomac120.NodePrinter;

/**
 * Created by elijah on 6/28/16.
 */
public class PrintableNodePosition implements Comparable<PrintableNodePosition> {
    public final int row;
    public final int column;
    public final PrintableNodeInfo nodeInfo;
    public PrintableNodePosition(PrintableNodeInfo nodeInfo, int row, int column){
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.nodeInfo = nodeInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PrintableNodePosition o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.column,o.column);
    }
}
```

And, finally, Node Interface

```
package com.tomac120.NodePrinter;

/**
 * Created by elijah on 6/28/16.
 */
public interface PrintableNode {
    PrintableNodeInfo _getPrintableNodeInfo();
    PrintableNode _getLeftChild();
    PrintableNode _getRightChild();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Scala solution, adapted from Vasya Novikov's answer and specialized for binary trees:

```
/** An immutable Binary Tree. */
case class BTree[T](value: T, left: Option[BTree[T]], right: Option[BTree[T]]) {

  /* Adapted from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8948691/643684 */
  def pretty: String = {
    def work(tree: BTree[T], prefix: String, isTail: Boolean): String = {
      val (line, bar) = if (isTail) ("└── ", " ") else ("├── ", "│")

      val curr = s"${prefix}${line}${tree.value}"

      val rights = tree.right match {
        case None    => s"${prefix}${bar}   ├── ∅"
        case Some(r) => work(r, s"${prefix}${bar}   ", false)
      }

      val lefts = tree.left match {
        case None    => s"${prefix}${bar}   └── ∅"
        case Some(l) => work(l, s"${prefix}${bar}   ", true)
      }

      s"${curr}\n${rights}\n${lefts}"

    }

    work(this, "", true)
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW, I've decided to post a Scala solution, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43348945/1091436

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to visualize your tree:  save the nodes as an xml file and then let your browser show you the hierarchy:

```
class treeNode{
    int key;
    treeNode left;
    treeNode right;

    public treeNode(int key){
        this.key = key;
        left = right = null;
    }

    public void printNode(StringBuilder output, String dir){
        output.append("<node key='" + key + "' dir='" + dir + "'>");
        if(left != null)
            left.printNode(output, "l");
        if(right != null)
            right.printNode(output, "r");
        output.append("</node>");
    }
}

class tree{
    private treeNode treeRoot;

    public tree(int key){
        treeRoot = new treeNode(key);
    }

    public void insert(int key){
        insert(treeRoot, key);
    }

    private treeNode insert(treeNode root, int key){
        if(root == null){
            treeNode child = new treeNode(key);
            return child;
        }

        if(key < root.key)
            root.left = insert(root.left, key);
        else if(key > root.key)
            root.right = insert(root.right, key);

        return root;
    }

    public void saveTreeAsXml(){
        StringBuilder strOutput = new StringBuilder();
        strOutput.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        treeRoot.printNode(strOutput, "root");
        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:/tree.xml", "UTF-8");
            writer.write(strOutput.toString());
            writer.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){

        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){

        }
    }
}
```

Here is code to test it:

```
    tree t = new tree(1);
    t.insert(10);
    t.insert(5);
    t.insert(4);
    t.insert(20);
    t.insert(40);
    t.insert(30);
    t.insert(80);
    t.insert(60);
    t.insert(50);

    t.saveTreeAsXml();
```

And the output looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
using map...
{
Map<Integer,String> m = new LinkedHashMap<>();

         tn.printNodeWithLvl(node,l,m);

        for(Entry<Integer, String> map :m.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(map.getValue());
        }
then....method


   private  void printNodeWithLvl(Node node,int l,Map<Integer,String> m) {
       if(node==null) {
           return;
       }
      if(m.containsKey(l)) {
          m.put(l, new StringBuilder(m.get(l)).append(node.value).toString());
      }else {
          m.put(l, node.value+"");
      }
      l++;
      printNodeWithLvl( node.left,l,m);
      printNodeWithLvl(node.right,l,m);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal representation is a little complex compared to vertical representation. Vertical printing is just plain RNL(Right->Node->left or mirror of inorder) traversal so that right subtree is printed first then left subtree.

```py
def printFullTree(root, delim=' ', idnt=[], left=None):
    if root:
        idnt.append(delim)
        x, y = setDelims(left)
        printFullTree(root.right, x, idnt, False)
        indent2(root.val, idnt)
        printFullTree(root.left, y, idnt, True)
        idnt.pop()

def setDelims(left):
    x = ' '; y='|'
    return (y,x) if (left == True) else (x,y) if (left == False) else (x,x)

def indent2(x, idnt, width=6):
    for delim in idnt:
        print(delim + ' '*(width-1), end='')
    print('|->', x)
```

```py
output:
                        |-> 15
                  |-> 14
                  |     |-> 13
            |-> 12
            |     |     |-> 11
            |     |-> 10
            |           |-> 9
      |-> 8
            |           |-> 7
            |     |-> 6
            |     |     |-> 4
            |-> 3
                  |     |-> 2
                  |-> 1
                        |-> 0
```

In horizontal representation, the display is built by HashMap of TreeMap or `HashMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, Object>> xy;` where HashMap contains node's y-axis/level_no as Key and TreeMap as value. The Treemap interally holds all nodes in same level, sorted by their x axis value as key starting from leftmost -ve, root=0, rightmost=+ve.

Using HashMap makes algo work in O(1) lookup for each level and TreeMap for sorted order in O(logn) if self balancing tree/Treap is used.

Still while doing so don't forget to store placeholders for null child such as ' '/spaces so that the tree looks as intended.

Now the only thing left is to calculate horizontal node distance, this can be done with some math calc,

1. calc tree width and height.
2. once done, when displaying the nodes, present them at a optimal distance based on calculated width, height, and skew info if any.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void print(int[] minHeap, int minWidth) {

    int size = minHeap.length;

    int level = log2(size);
    int maxLength = (int) Math.pow(2, level) * minWidth;
    int currentLevel = -1 ;
    int width = maxLength;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (log2(i + 1) > currentLevel) {
            currentLevel++;
            System.out.println();
            width = maxLength / (int) Math.pow(2, currentLevel);
        }
        System.out.print(StringUtils.center(String.valueOf(minHeap[i]), width));
    }
    System.out.println();
}

private static int log2(int n) {
    return (int) (Math.log(n) / Math.log(2));
}
```

The idea of this code snippet is dividing the maxLength which is the length of bottom line by the number of elements of each line to get the block width. Then put the element in the middle of each block.

The parameter minWidth implys the length of blocks in the bottom line.

[A picture to illustrate the idea and show the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOryX.png)