# How can I access Maven Artifact POM using Maven's Java API?

Tags: java, maven

I am attempting to retrieve the entire dependency tree and their poms starting at the root of the project.  I am starting with a POM already existing in my file system, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the dependency poms from the repository.

I am using the following code to access the dependency list.  From the list I have all the information on the artifacts.  I'm just not sure how to access the repository.

```
FileReader reader = null;
Model model = null;
MavenXpp3Reader mavenreader = new MavenXpp3Reader();

File pomfile = new File("pom.xml");

model.setPomFile(pomfile);
MavenProject project = new MavenProject(model);

List<Dependency> deps = project.getDependencies();

// Get dependency details
for (Dependency d: deps) {          
    System.out.print(d.getArtifactId());
    System.out.print(":");
    System.out.println(d.getVersion()); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you were pretty close to reading the dependencies. All that was missing was:

```
Model model = mavenreader.read(new FileReader(pomFile));
```

Full example:

```
MavenXpp3Reader mavenreader = new MavenXpp3Reader();

File pomfile = new File("pom.xml");
Model model = mavenreader.read(new FileReader(pomFile));

List<Dependency> deps = model.getDependencies();

for (Dependency d: deps) {          
    System.out.print(d.getArtifactId());
}
```

This doesn't get you a dependency tree but you can repeat it for the dependencies you find.

Answer (score 1):

Unfotunately that is not that trivial :-) I can give you some advices though (taking into account that you need artifacts only from the central repo).

Here's a great [example code](https://github.com/rlegendi/maven-indexer-examples/blob/master/indexer-example-01/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/indexer/example/App.java) I found at Github. An alternative could be using the [REST API of the central repo](http://search.maven.org/#api). Here's an example how to [do that programmatically](http://code.google.com/p/dependency-checker-for-java-applications/source/browse/trunk/src/net/ogi/maven/net/ArtifactsGetter.java).

BTW if you need the dependencies only, you could also use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/source-repository.html) directly (this is called on e.g. `mvn dependency:tree` - see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861794/print-plain-text-tree-from-tree-data-structure-java/10862269#10862269) for an example).

Probably your method can also work, but I guess it needs some missing parts.

Comment: I'm actually trying to programmaticaly retrieve the poms from my local repository (not the central repo) using the Maven API.  I could look for the local repository through the file system, but this needs to be able to work anywhere with any user, so I thought that the API would be more appropriate.

Comment: @rlegendi I don't know your use case but if you need only the dependencies of some public maven libraries you can use the VersionEye API: https://www.versioneye.com/api?version=v2. It is a REST JSON API and very easy to use.

Comment: @RobertReiz Didn't you want to address your comment to @davdic? :-) Anyway, thx for the link, but it seems commercial and a beta product.

Comment: @rlegendi Yes. It is out of Beta now. it is commercial but the API you can use for free.

Comment: @rlegendi In the mean while we have even a maven plugin. Check it out here: https://github.com/versioneye/versioneye_maven_plugin. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @RobertReiz Hey Robert, thx for the ping! Let me take a look at it! :-)