# How do I Get a Maven Project's Parent POM using the Java API?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have a Java project that needs to access Maven properties of another project, which it can access on the file system but has no Maven relationship with - no dependency, parent, plugin, or anything. I found out how to get the object project's POM into the API using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658087/how-can-i-access-maven-artifact-pom-using-mavens-java-api). However, the property I want (`jasperreports.version`) is inherited from the object project's parent project.

It turns out the `getProperties()` method of the project that I obtained using the MavenXpp3Reader only contains explicitly mentioned properties, not the ones inherited from the parent. In general, the model (`org.apache.maven.model.Model`) is pretty much just a syntax tree of the XML. I thought it could be a nice workaround to just duplicate the property in the child POM:

```
<properties>
    <jasperreports.version2>${jasperreports.version}</jasperreports.version2>
    ...
</properties>
```

and the properties map at the end just contained the literal string `${jasperreports.version}`.

I cannot use the `<parent>/<relativePath>` property to locate and then manually parse the parent POM, because the parent project will eventually be in a Maven repository instead of being a parent directory. It's a pretty brittle solution anyway. The child project whose POM I am reading will remain accessible as a file, though.

It would be great if I could just get the effective POM of the project as an `org.apache.maven.model.Model` or `org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject` which would include all properties from parents with filtering and everything. Is there a way to do this? Or a way I can at least get a `Model` for the parent project so I can get its properties?

Comment: Is your current project and the project that contains the required properties are in any kind of relationship via parent/child or an other module? Can you explain that more in detail? Why would you like to use Java API? Are you within a plugin ?

Comment: No Maven relationship, just access to the project and its POM on the file system. I added this to the initial prompt, is it clear now?