# java drawing graphs or trees in console

Tags: java, graphics, charts, console, command-line-interface

Does anyone know a mean to "render" plots or at least trees in console mode (draw it in the console)?

I would be able to render small plots at end of a very long process, by drawing some figures in ASCII mode, in order to have a geeky & fun view of some stats collected into the process.

I would be pleased to discover a library which does that, and I would keep the process 100% java, no shell-hack or third-party software.

-- EDIT

@lbalazscs and @Fortega made interesting answers, but the background of my question is to know *if it exists* such a library, and I will add some details I missed the first time :

The output should be able to display trees, binary trees ([linked by @lbalazscs here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965335/how-to-print-binary-tree-diagram)), but *also* simple graphs such as bargraphs or so.

I will let this question "unanswered" for a while, and if there is no probant answer, @lbalazscs will get the point ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For people coming here looking for a pure Java tree drawing library: I recommend [text-tree](https://gitlab.com/barfuin/text-tree), which draws trees like this (and other styles, a lot of possible config if you need it):

```
some text
├─── more text
├─── and more
│    ├─── still more
│    ╰─── more
╰─── the end
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author of text-tree.*

Answer (score 5):

You can print ascii trees with minimal code. See the second answer to this question: [How to print binary tree diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965335/how-to-print-binary-tree-diagram)

(the second answer because this one is not only for binary trees)

Comment: Ow Yeah ! Thanks for this interesting post !

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well, you can draw ascii graphs with [javaplot](http://gnujavaplot.sourceforge.net/JavaPlot/About.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however it requires to have *third-party* sofware installed (GNUPlot), which I would avoid to deal with. However, +1 for making me discover this cool lib, which I will use elsewhere.