# Print an AVL Tree : Java

Tags: java, data-structures, avl-tree

I've created an AVL Tree, with working Add and Remove methods. However, I need to print out the tree in a visual format. something like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrBf2.png)
is there a relatively short way of doing so? 
(You can assume that i have the height of every node).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there's any easy way to display the data in an AVL tree besides inorder, postorder, and preorder list representations.

However, I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965335/how-to-print-binary-tree-diagram) solution on an old Stack Overflow question.