# How to print A binary tree?

Tags: java, printing, binary-tree

how can i send (node.data) from `SortTree` Class to `TreePrinter` then used to print A Tree .

```
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;


public class SortTree {

static Node root;
TreePrinter type =new TreePrinter();

class Node<A extends Comparable>{

int data;
Node left, right;

Node(int d) {
     data = d;
     left = null;
 right = null;
}
} 

Node sortedArrayToBST(int arr[], int start, int end) {  
if (start > end) {
    return null;
}

int mid = (start + end) / 2;
Node node = new Node(arr[mid]);
node.left = sortedArrayToBST(arr, start, mid - 1);
node.right = sortedArrayToBST(arr, mid + 1, end);       
return node;
}
void preOrder(Node node) {
if (node == null) {
    return;
}
//System.out.print(node.data + " ");
preOrder(node.left);
preOrder(node.right);
}  
}
```

And this is TreePrinter class :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class TreePrinter {

public static class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
T value;
Node<T> left, right;

public void insertToTree(T v) {
if (value == null) {
    value = v;
    return;
}
if (v.compareTo(value) < 0) {
    if (left == null) {
        left = new Node<T>();
    }
    left.insertToTree(v);
} else {
    if (right == null) {
        right = new Node<T>();
    }
    right.insertToTree(v);
}
}

public void printTree(OutputStreamWriter out) throws IOException {
if (right != null) {
    right.printTree(out, true, "");
}
printNodeValue(out);
if (left != null) {
    left.printTree(out, false, "");
}
}

private void printNodeValue(OutputStreamWriter out) throws IOException {
if (value == null) {
    out.write("<null>");
} else {
    out.write(value.toString());
}
out.write('\n');
}

private void printTree(OutputStreamWriter out, boolean isRight, String indent) throws IOException {
if (right != null) {
    right.printTree(out, true, indent + (isRight ? "        " : " |      "));
}
out.write(indent);
if (isRight) {
    out.write("┌");
} else {
    out.write("└");
}
out.write("────");
printNodeValue(out);
if (left != null) {
    left.printTree(out, false, indent + (isRight ? " |      " : "      "));
}
}}}
```

nodes sorted as preorder any help to send `(node.data)` to `treeprinter` class then type the tree:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you implement a toString, rather than this TreePrinter.

I've slightly changed your Node class, moved it outside the SortTree, resulting in the code available from https://github.com/johanwitters/stackoverflow-tree-printer.

The implementation of Node is here:

```
package com.johanw.stackoverflow.tree;

import com.johanw.stackoverflow.util.Helper;

public class Node<A extends Comparable>{
    private static int AMOUNT_INDENT = 3;

    private int data;
    private Node left, right;

    public Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    public void setLeft(Node left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public void setRight(Node right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public Node getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void indent(StringBuilder builder, int indent) {
        builder.append(Helper.repeat(indent * (AMOUNT_INDENT + 1), " "));
    }

    public void newLine(StringBuilder builder) {
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    public String toString(int indent) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(data);
        newLine(builder);
        if (left != null) {
            indent(builder, indent);
            builder.append("└" + Helper.repeat(AMOUNT_INDENT, "─") + left.toString(indent + 1));
        }
        if (right != null) {
            indent(builder, indent);
            builder.append("└" + Helper.repeat(AMOUNT_INDENT, "─") + right.toString(indent + 1));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toString(0);
    }
}
```

The below unit test gives the bottom output for the given tree structure:

```
public class TestSortTree {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Node node = new Node(1);
        Node left = new Node(2);
        Node leftLeft = new Node(22);
        Node leftRight = new Node(23);
        Node leftRightLeft = new Node(24);
        left.setLeft(leftLeft);
        leftRight.setLeft(new Node(39));
        left.setRight(leftRight);
        node.setLeft(left);
        node.setRight(new Node(3));
        System.out.println(node.toString());
    }
}
```

[image]

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to receive the node.data in `TreePrinter`. I would add the following code

```
class TreePrinter<T extends Comparable<T>>{
    Node<T extends Comparable<T>> root;

    public TreePrinter(){
        root = new Node<T extends Comparable<T>>();
    }

    public void insertToTree(T v) {
        root.insertToTree(v);
    }
```

It will now be easy printing the tree using the algorithm from this post:

[How to print binary tree diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965335/how-to-print-binary-tree-diagram)

I would send the data by making the following modification to `Node sortedArrayToBST(int arr[], int start, int end)` in `SortTree`

```
void sortedArrayToBST(int arr[], int start, int end) {  
    if (start > end) {
        return;
    }

    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    type.insertToTree(arr[mid]);
    node.left = sortedArrayToBST(arr, start, mid - 1);
    node.right = sortedArrayToBST(arr, mid + 1, end);
}
```

I have not tried running this so might need some debugging, but I think the underlying idea is solid. Hope this helps!