# How to display binary search tree rotated 90deg which starts from lowest point

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, printing, binary-search-tree

I have created a Binary Search Tree as follows:

```
static class TreeNode{
    private int data;
    private TreeNode leftChild;
    private TreeNode rightChild;

    public TreeNode(int data){
        this.data=data;
    }

    public void add(int data){
        if( data >= this.data){
            if(this.rightChild == null){
                this.rightChild = new TreeNode(data);
            }else{
                this.rightChild.add(data);
            }
        }else {
            if(this.leftChild == null){
                this.leftChild = new TreeNode(data);
            }else {
                this.leftChild.add(data);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }
    public  void setLeftChild(TreeNode leftChild){
        this.leftChild = leftChild;
    }
    public  void setRightChild(TreeNode rightChild){
        this.rightChild = rightChild;
    }
    public TreeNode getLeftChild(){
        return leftChild;
    }
    public TreeNode getRightChild(){
        return rightChild;
    }
    public void print() {
        print("", this, false);
    }

    public void print(String prefix, TreeNode n, boolean isLeft) {
        if (n != null) {
            System.out.println (prefix + (isLeft ? "|-- " : "\\-- ") + n.data);
            print(prefix + (isLeft ? "|   " : "    "), n.leftChild, true);
            print(prefix + (isLeft ? "|   " : "    "), n.rightChild, false);
        }
    }
}

static class BinaryTree{

  private TreeNode root;

  public void pprint(){
      traversePreOrder(this.root);
  }

  public void traversePreOrder(TreeNode node) {
      if (node != null) {
          System.out.print(" " + node.data);
          traversePreOrder(node.leftChild);
          traversePreOrder(node.rightChild);
      }
  }
}
```

I want to display my tree, however not normally, but in rotated 90deg, which starts from the lowest point.

For example: if the input is: 901 292 247 997 457 468 216 82 530 524 793 952 730 764 820 460 424

The output should look like this:

[image]

Another Example: if the input is: 302 946 638 376 604 610 45 547 76 347 694 495 51 130 159

Output:

[image]

P.S I tried with the information in [How to print binary tree diagram in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965335/how-to-print-binary-tree-diagram-in-java), but I was unable to solve the issue :(

Comment: How does your output looks like at the moment? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well I am able to display the tree  Inorder, however the rotation part and the fact that the tree should start from the lowest points makes the solution quite harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- You should not need to pass a node instance as argument when you already have the current (`this`) instance.
- `pprint` never calls the `print` method on the `TreeNode` class
- The `print` method on the `TreeNode` class visits the nodes in pre-order. For in-order, you should first visit the left subtree, then the node itself and then the right subtree

Here is a correction to the `print` methods in `TreeNode`:

```
class TreeNode{

    /* ... constructor and other methods here ... */

    public void print() {
        print("", "", "", "");
    }

    public void print(String prefix, String left, String mid, String right) {
        String indent = " ".repeat(String.valueOf(data).length());
        if (leftChild != null) {
            leftChild.print(prefix + left + indent, " ", "┌", "│");
        }
        System.out.println(prefix + mid + data 
                           + " ┐┘┤".charAt((leftChild  != null ? 2 : 0) 
                                         + (rightChild != null ? 1 : 0)));
        if (rightChild != null) {
            rightChild.print(prefix + right + indent, "│", "└", " ");
        }
    }
}
```

And in `BinaryTree` we would simply defer the job to the `TreeNode` class:

```
class BinaryTree {
    private TreeNode root;

    public void pprint() {
        if (root != null) {
            root.print();
        }
    }

    public void add(int data) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new TreeNode(data);
        } else {
            root.add(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works!!, I am also interested, how can we return the output as a String, and not just printing it, I want to save it in a String variable, how can do make so?

Comment: Yes, that is possible, and is actually better practice. Printing should not be done in methods really. Have a go at it, and try to change this into a string-returning method (concatenate the strings you get from recursive calls). If you cannot make it work, then ask a specific question about it (new question).

Comment: I have noticed that every last number, which does not have a left or right node has an extra space " " for example in second example 51 159 347 495 610 694 have all white spaces on the right side, how can i remove spaces from those elements?

Comment: Do you know `trim()`?

Comment: Yes, but where should i add it? I mean i only want to add it to the TreeNodes, which don't have left and right childs.

Comment: Okay i will try my best, and i will write you my results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235596/discussion-between-givi-and-trincot).

Answer (score 0):

Some observations:

- If you want the nodes to show up at the correct positions, you must use **in-order** traversal in your recursive function: Descend left, then print, then descend right.
- There is **no constant prefix** for each node. In your second example, when you go left from 76, you must print the connection between 76 and 45, but if you go right, there is no connection at the same depth.

  You can solve this by keeping a **history of directions**, for example as string of L's and R's.
- Each node has a "**postfix**" that depends on whether it has a left or right child or both.
- The numbers must be **padded** to a fixed width, so that the "postfix" lines up with the connections.

I don't speak Java, but here's some Javascript-like pseudocode that sould achieve what you want:

```
function tree_print(n, path) {
    if (n) {
        // determine prefix

        let prefix = "";

        if (path.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 1; i < path.length; i++) {
                prefix += (path[i] == path[i - 1]) ? "     "
                                                   : "    │";
            }
            
            prefix += (path[path.length - 1] == "L") ? "    ┌"
                                                     : "    └";
        }

        // determine postfix
        
        let post = 0;
        if (n.left) post |= 1;
        if (n.right) post |= 2;

        let postfix = " ┘┐┤"[post];
    
        tree_print(n.left, path + "L");
        print(prefix + pad(n.value) + postfix);
        tree_print(n.right, path + "R");
    } 
}
```

Call it (hypothetically) with:

```
tree_print(root, "");
```