# How to print binary tree diagram in Dart?

Tags: dart, binary-tree

I have a binary tree node like this:

```dart
class BinaryTreeNode<T> {
  BinaryTreeNode(this.value, {this.leftChild, this.rightChild});
  T value;
  BinaryTreeNode? leftChild;
  BinaryTreeNode? rightChild;
}
```

I'd like to add a `toString` method so that I can have a visual representation of the contents of the binary tree.

This is a Dart version of [this Java question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965335/how-to-print-binary-tree-diagram-in-java). I was able to port one of the answers there so I am adding it below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a modified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19484210):

```dart
class BinaryTreeNode<T> {
  BinaryTreeNode(this.value, {this.leftChild, this.rightChild});
  T value;
  BinaryTreeNode<T>? leftChild;
  BinaryTreeNode<T>? rightChild;

  @override
  String toString() {
    final out = StringBuffer();

    rightChild?._buildTree(out, true, '');
    out.writeln(value);
    leftChild?._buildTree(out, false, '');

    return out.toString();
  }

  void _buildTree(StringBuffer out, bool isRight, String indent) {
    rightChild?._buildTree(out, true, indent + (isRight ? '     ' : '│    '));

    out
      ..write(indent)
      ..write(isRight ? '┌─── ' : '└─── ')
      ..writeln(value);

    leftChild?._buildTree(out, false, indent + (isRight ? '│    ' : '     '));
  }
}
```

If you build a tree like so:

```dart
void main() {
  final tree = BinaryTreeNode('D',
      leftChild: BinaryTreeNode('A'),
      rightChild: BinaryTreeNode(
        'R',
        leftChild: BinaryTreeNode('T'),
        rightChild: BinaryTreeNode('Fun'),
      ));
  print(tree);
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
     ┌─── Fun
┌─── R
│    └─── T
D
└─── A
```

Feel free to modify my answer to simply the code. I feel like the `toString` method could be simplified to not repeat so much code.

### Suggested solution from lrn

The following solution is more efficient since we are avoiding creating intermediate string objects as we go though the tree structure. Thanks to lrn for suggesting this approach:

```dart
class BinaryTreeNode<T> {
  BinaryTreeNode(this.value, {this.leftChild, this.rightChild});

  T value;
  BinaryTreeNode<T>? leftChild;
  BinaryTreeNode<T>? rightChild;

  @override
  String toString() {
    final out = StringBuffer();

    final indents = <String>[];
    rightChild?._buildTree(out, true, indents);
    out.writeln(value);
    leftChild?._buildTree(out, false, indents);

    return out.toString();
  }

  void _buildTree(StringBuffer out, bool isRight, List<String> indents) {
    if (rightChild != null) {
      indents.add(isRight ? '     ' : '│    ');
      rightChild!._buildTree(out, true, indents);
      indents.removeLast();
    }

    out
      ..writeAll(indents)
      ..write(isRight ? '┌─── ' : '└─── ')
      ..writeln(value);

    if (leftChild != null) {
      indents.add(isRight ? '│    ' : '     ');
      leftChild!._buildTree(out, false, indents);
      indents.removeLast();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated the solution with use of `writeln` (instead of `write('\n')` and `?.` operator instead of `if (value != null)`. Also added use of cascade operator (..). And at last, I thought it would make more sense to have `leftChild` and `rightChild` to follow the same generic as the parent (so `BinaryTreeNode<T>` instead of `BinaryTreeNode`). See the last change as a personal artistic choice not really needed. :)

Comment: Made some minor adjustments to the layout so the first lines is not shifted by one to make it more consistent with the rest. I hope that is okay. :)

Comment: @julemand101, That's amazing! Learning from people like you is why I like posting public answers online.

Comment: If you want to optimize for performance (who doesn't?!?), you could make `indent` a `List<String>`, where you `add` the next layer before calling recursively, and remove it again with `removeLast` when coming back, and then adds all of the indents to the string buffer. That avoids creating intermediate string objects, but does add more individual strings to the `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @lrn Added your suggested solution. Please change it I have misunderstood your intention. :)

Comment: Perfect. Only changed it to use `StringBuffer.writeAll` to write all the indents in one call.