# AVL Tree traversal postOrder

Tags: java, avl-tree, tree-traversal, postorder

I'm learning data structures, and I'm building an AVL tree class. I want to traverse the tree by saving the elements in one string. I already built the three functions that traverse over the tree in {inorder,preorder,postorder} recursively on the console. I wonder how I can modify the code to load the result into a string, and not the console.

I will post the code for postorder down here:

```java
void printPostorder(Node root) { // prints the tree in post order     left right root
    if (root == null)
        return;
    printPostorder(root.left);
    printPostorder(root.right);
    System.out.print(root.element + " ");
}
```

Comment: Please tag the language you are using.

Comment: The simplest (I don't say best) way would probably be, defining a string outside of the function and instead of printing to the console just appending to the string.

Comment: Using StringBuilder is better than using a String

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you made your `printPostorder` or `printPostorder` but you could use a string builder

```java
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
// you might want to do this recursively or with a loop though
str.append(printPostorder(root.left).toString);
str.append(printPostorder(root.right).toString);
```

Also for something more interesting, see [How to print binary tree diagram in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965335/how-to-print-binary-tree-diagram-in-java)