# Printing binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have been trying for a while to identify why the tree is printing with indentation for the first time around. I'm trying to make it so that it doesn't print with indentation on the first time.

```
public void printTree() {
    UI.clearText();
    printTreeHelper(theTree, ""); // Print without indentation and no initial answer.
    UI.println();
    UI.println("Completion version:");
    printTreeHelper(theTree, ""); // Print with indentation and no initial answer.
}

private void printTreeHelper(DTNode node, String indentation) {
    if (node != null) {
        String nodeText = indentation + (indentation.isEmpty() ? "" : " ") + node.getText();
        UI.println(nodeText); // Print the current node's text with or without indentation.
        printTreeHelper(node.getYes(), indentation + "  "); // Continue for "yes" child with increased indentation.
        printTreeHelper(node.getNo(), indentation + "  "); // Continue for "no" child with increased indentation.
    }
}
```

[THe picture of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enody.png)
vs
[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzfPu.png)

I tried many things but didn't work

Comment: can add sample output so that we can get clear picture on which indentation you are talking about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print binary tree diagram in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965335/how-to-print-binary-tree-diagram-in-java)Why couldn't the questioner do a search first?

Comment: @Nidhi257 its up now

Comment: @时间只会一直走 that is different, i added images so that u can see what it is supposed to look like

Comment: You haven't looked at that question carefully at all. The answer below has a solution to your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53705889/3553434 This is almost exactly what you need, at least with a little modification! 
You can refer to this. and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42449385/3553434

Answer (score 1):

The reason why indent is printing on first time around is because you are using `indentation` variable both for adding extra spacing and for checking if you are in a root node or not.

Try setting up new boolean parameter to identify the first node vs the `indentation` String.

> `boolean isFirst`

Here is how you do it:

```
public void printTree() {
    UI.clearText();
    printTreeHelper(theTree, "", true); // Print without indentation for the first node.
    UI.println();
    UI.println("Completion version:");
    printTreeHelper(theTree, "", true); // Print with indentation for the first node.
}

private void printTreeHelper(DTNode node, String indentation, boolean isFirst) {
    if (node != null) {
        String nodeText;
        if (isFirst) {
            nodeText = node.getText(); // No indentation for the first node
        } else {
            nodeText = indentation + " " + node.getText(); // Indentation for all other nodes
        }
        UI.println(nodeText);
        printTreeHelper(node.getYes(), indentation + "  ", false); // Continue for "yes" child with increased indentation.
        printTreeHelper(node.getNo(), indentation + "  ", false); // Continue for "no" child with increased indentation.
    }
}
```

Basically what it does is it takes additional parameter on first check, if its `true` and if it is set to `false` and decide if it will add indentation or not.