# How do I print a tree structure over multiple pages?

Tags: c#, printing, tree

I need to create a large tree and print it with more than 10 levels.

My data is very large, and it won't fit on one page.  How do I get the tree to fit onto multiple pages?

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649027/how-do-i-print-out-a-tree-structure), but it doesn't show how I can spread the tree over multiple printed pages.

Comment: How would you print it to a single page? Are we talking to an HTML stream, an actual printer queue (using what technology?), or something else entirely?