# c# - Simple Binary Tree

Tags: c#, binary-tree

So, I have been learning C# over the past month and at the moment I am struggling with Binary Trees.

My question is that How am I able to call my tree to the Console Window? 
I've Tried `Console.WriteLine(tree.Data);` But this seems to Write 54 to my Console Window.

Here is my code if you need to check it out:

Main File

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Creating the Nodes for the Tree
    Node<int> tree = new Node<int>('6');
    tree.Left = new Node<int>('2');
    tree.Right = new Node<int>('5');  

    Console.WriteLine("Binary Tree Display");
    Console.WriteLine(tree.Data);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Node Class

```
class Node<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private T data;
    public Node<T> Left, Right;

    public Node(T item)
    {
        data = item;
        Left = null;
        Right = null;
    }
    public T Data
    {
        set { data = value; }
        get { return data; }
    }
}
```

Are there any other methods of calling my Tree? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify the answers below, you are converting a `char` type which you created by using the literal `'6'` with apostrophes. The `char` type is being implicitly converted to the equivalent `int` value, whereby integer value "54" represents the character `6`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why it's just showing `54` is because that is the what `(int)'6'` is!

You're calling `tree.Data` which returns in this case `'6'` cast to `int`.

---

I imagine what you're trying to do is either return `6` which you could do by using

```
new Node<char>('6');
```

or by

```
new Node<int>(6);
```

---

([More in separate answer, removed for clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17951190/1185053))

Comment: [to be continued..] sounds better :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: [Alternatively...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwbsx6LvnfY&t=0m51s) even more thrilling!

Answer (score 2):

```
Node<int> tree = new Node<int>(6);
```

6, and not '6'. Now expected value will be printed. Your code is silently casts char value '6' to integer, which gives result 54.

Answer (score 2):

([Moved from previous answer for clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17950646/1185053))

If you're trying to return all the data for your `Node<T>` I think a better way of going about it would be to override the `ToString` method in your `Node<T>` class like so:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    var leftString = this.Left != null ? this.Left.ToString() : "null";
    var rightString = this.Right != null ? this.Right.ToString() : "null";
    var dataString = this.Data != null ? this.Data.ToString() : "null";

    leftString = String.Join("\n", leftString.Split('\n').Select(a => "\t" + a));
    rightString = String.Join("\n", rightString.Split('\n').Select(a => "\t" + a));

    return String.Format("\nData: {0}\n"
                        + "Left: {1}\n"
                        + "Right: {2}",
                        dataString, leftString, rightString);
}
```

Then call `Console.WriteLine(tree.ToString());` which results in the following:

```
Data: 54
Left:   
  Data: 50
  Left:   null
  Right:   null
Right:   
  Data: 53
  Left:   null
  Right:   null
```

This isn't the prettiest implementation but I think proves the point.

For a prettier implementation see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1649223/1185053)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to do this would be to implement a concise recursive tree traversal algorithm which prints out the value of each node in the particular order you choose to encounter them. As for there being a pre-written method to do so within the C# libraries, I am not aware of it. Best of luck!