# How to compare strings that are passed as a template class?

Tags: c++, string, templates, comparison

I have a data structure that uses a template class such that it can store any data type - ints, floats, strings, etc.

Because the data will be organized, I need a way to compare two values. Usually I can use > or <, but in the case of strings that will not work because using the >/< operators on a string won't tell me which comes first alphabetically. For that, I need to use the compare() function.

However since the data structure is a template class, I can't tell it to use the compare() function because it won't recognize the compare() function for anything BUT a string.

As a work-around, I tried writing two compare functions:

```
template (class t)
int BinaryTree<T>::compareVals(T v1, T v2);
```

and

```
template (class t)
int BinaryTree<T>::compareVals(string v1, string v2);
```

So that in the case of the value being a string type, the program would use the method with the compare() function in it.

However trying to do that, I am getting a compiler error basically telling me I can't overload the function.

So I'm out of ideas. How can I make this template class correctly compare and sort strings as well as numbers?

Thank you very much for your input!

Here is the entire class, for reference:

```
#ifndef binarytree_class
#define binarytree_class

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout; 
using std::string;
using std::vector;

template <class T>
class BinaryTree{
    public:
        struct TreeNode{
            TreeNode * leftChild, 
                     * rightChild;
            T key;
            vector<T> data;
            int size;
        };

        BinaryTree();
        ~BinaryTree();
        bool isEmpty();
        int getSize();
        void add(T key, T data);
        void remove(T key);
        int getHeight();
        bool keyExists(T key);
        int getKeyHeight(T key);
        void displayAll();                    

    private: 
        int size;
        TreeNode * root;

        TreeNode * findParent(TreeNode * start, TreeNode * child); //finds the parent node of child in subtree starting at root start
        TreeNode * findNode(TreeNode * node, T input); //find node with data input in subtree at root node
        TreeNode * findMin(TreeNode * node);     
        void removeNode(TreeNode * node);      //Small part of algorithm (case: 2 children) borrowed from tech-faq.com/binary-tree-deleting-a-node.html
        void displaySubTree(TreeNode * node);  //displays subtree starting at node
        void sortAdd(TreeNode * eNode, TreeNode * nNode);  //adds a new node nNode to subtree starting at root eNode  
        void destroySubTree(TreeNode * node);  //destroys subtree starting at node. 
        void display(TreeNode * node, string indent, bool last); //Algorithm borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649027/how-do-i-print-out-a-tree-structure
        char leftOrRight(TreeNode * eNode, TreeNode * nNode); //compares keys in existing node vs new node and returns L or R
        int calcHeight(TreeNode * node, int depth);  //calculates the height from node. Algorithm borrowed from wiki.answers.com
        int compareVals(T v1, T v2);
        int compareVals(string v1, string v2);      
};

template <class T>
BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree<T>() : size(0){}

template <class T>
bool BinaryTree<T>::isEmpty(){
    return (!size);
}

template <class T> 
int BinaryTree<T>::compareVals(T v1, T v2){
    int result;
    v1 <= v2? result = -1 : result = 1;
    return result;
}

template <class T> 
int BinaryTree<T>::compareVals(string v1, string v2){
    int result;
    result = v1.compare(v2);
    if(result >= 0)
        result = -1;
    else
        result = 1;
    return result;
}

template <class T>
int BinaryTree<T>::getSize(){
    return size;
}

template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::add(T key, T data){
    bool done = false;
    TreeNode * temp;

    if(keyExists(key)){
        temp = findNode(root,key);
        temp->size++;
        temp->data.push_back(key); 
    }
    else{
        temp = new TreeNode;
        temp->leftChild = 0;
        temp->rightChild = 0;
        temp->key = key;
        temp->size = 0;
        temp->data.push_back(data);        
        if(isEmpty())
            root = temp;   
        else
            sortAdd(root, temp);
       size++; 
    }
}

template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::sortAdd(TreeNode * eNode, TreeNode * nNode){
    if(leftOrRight(eNode, nNode) == 'L'){
        if(eNode->leftChild == 0)
            eNode->leftChild = nNode;
        else
            sortAdd(eNode->leftChild,nNode);
    } else {
        if(eNode->rightChild == 0)
            eNode->rightChild = nNode;
        else
            sortAdd(eNode->rightChild,nNode);
    }
}

template <class T>
char BinaryTree<T>::leftOrRight(TreeNode * eNode, TreeNode * nNode){
    char result;
    if(compareVals(nNode->key, eNode->key) == -1)
        result = 'L';
    else
        result = 'R';
    return result;
}

template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::displayAll(){
    display(root,"",true);    
}

template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::display(TreeNode * node, string indent, bool last){
    if(!isEmpty()){
        cout << indent;
        if(last){
            cout << "\\-";
            indent += " ";  
        } else {
            cout << "|-";
            indent += "| ";
        }
        cout << node->key << "\n";
        if(node->leftChild != 0)
            display(node->leftChild, indent, false);
        if(node->rightChild != 0)
            display(node->rightChild, indent, true); 
    } else
        cout << "TREE IS EMPTY" << "\n\n";
}

template <class T>
int BinaryTree<T>::getHeight(){
      if(!root)
        cout << "ERROR: getHeight() root is NULL!" << "\n";
      int result;
      if(isEmpty())
            result = 0;
      else
            result = calcHeight(root, 1);
      return result;
}

template <class T>
int BinaryTree<T>::getKeyHeight(T key){
    int result = -1;
    if(!keyExists(key))
        cout << "ERROR: Trying to get height of nonexistant key " << key << "\n";
    else{
        TreeNode * temp = findNode(root, key);    
        result = getHeight() - calcHeight(temp,1);
    }
    return result;
}

template <class T>
int BinaryTree<T>::calcHeight(TreeNode * node, int depth){ //Algorithm borrowed from wiki.answers.com
    int leftDepth,
        rightDepth,
        result;
    if(node->leftChild)
        leftDepth = calcHeight(node->leftChild, depth+1);
    else
        leftDepth = depth;
    if(node->rightChild)
        rightDepth = calcHeight(node->rightChild, depth+1);
    else
        rightDepth = depth;
    if(leftDepth > rightDepth)     
        result = leftDepth;
    else
        result = rightDepth;
    return result;
}

template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::remove(T input){
    if(!keyExists(input))
        cout << "ERR: trying to remove nonexistant key " << input << "\n";
    else{
        TreeNode * temp = findNode(root,input);
        removeNode(temp);
    }      
}

template <class T>
bool BinaryTree<T>::keyExists(T key){
    bool result;
    if(isEmpty())
        result = false;
    else{
        if(findNode(root,key) != 0)
            result = true;
        else
            result = false;
    }   
    return result;    
}


template <class T>
typename BinaryTree<T>::TreeNode * BinaryTree<T>::findNode(TreeNode * node, T input){
    TreeNode *  result = 0;     //Returns 0 if none found
    if(node->key == input)
        result = node;
    else{
        if(node->leftChild != 0)
            result = findNode(node->leftChild, input);
        if(result == 0 && node->rightChild != 0)
            result = findNode(node->rightChild, input);
    }
    return result;
}

template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::removeNode(TreeNode * node){
    TreeNode * parent = 0;
    if(node != root)
        parent = findParent(root,node);

    if(node->leftChild && node->rightChild){                    //Case: both children (algorithm borrowed from tech-faq.com)
        TreeNode * temp = findMin(node->rightChild);  
        string tkey = temp->key;
        removeNode(temp); 
        node->key = tkey;
    } else {
        if(parent){                                             
            if(!(node->leftChild) && !(node->rightChild)){      //case: no children & not root
                if(parent->leftChild == node)
                    parent->leftChild = 0;
                else
                    parent->rightChild = 0;    
            }    
            if(!(node->leftChild) && node->rightChild){         //case: right child only & not root
                if(parent->leftChild == node)
                    parent->leftChild = node->rightChild;
                else
                    parent->rightChild = node->rightChild;    
            }
            if(node->leftChild && !(node->rightChild)){         //case: left child only & not root
                if(parent->leftChild == node)
                    parent->leftChild = node->leftChild;
                else
                    parent->rightChild = node->leftChild;    
            }
            delete node;
            size--;
        }
        else{
            if(node->leftChild)                             //case: left child only & root
                root = node->leftChild;
            else                                           //case: right child only & root
                root = node->rightChild;
            delete node;                                   //case: no children & root intrinsically covered
            size--;    
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
typename BinaryTree<T>::TreeNode * BinaryTree<T>::findMin(TreeNode * node){
    TreeNode * result;
    if(node->leftChild == 0)
        result = node;
    else
        result = findMin(node->leftChild);
    return result;
}

template <class T>
typename BinaryTree<T>::TreeNode * BinaryTree<T>::findParent(TreeNode * start, TreeNode * child){
    TreeNode * result = 0;

    if(start->leftChild){
        if(start->leftChild->key == child->key)
            result = start;   
        else 
            result = findParent(start->leftChild, child);
    }
    if(start->rightChild && result == 0){
        if(start->rightChild->key == child->key)
            result = start;    
        else
            result = findParent(start->rightChild, child);
    }
    return result;
}

template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::destroySubTree(TreeNode * node){
    TreeNode * parent = 0;
    if(node != root)
        parent = findParent(root,node);
    if(node->leftChild)
        destroySubTree(node->leftChild);
    if(node->rightChild)
        destroySubTree(node->rightChild);
    if(parent){
        if(parent->leftChild == node)
            parent->leftChild = 0;
        else
            parent->rightChild = 0;
    }   
    size--;
    delete node;    
}

template <class T>
BinaryTree<T>::~BinaryTree<T>(){
    if(!isEmpty())
        destroySubTree(root);
}



#endif
```

Comment: `std::string` supports relational operators like `==` and `<=` so you don't really need to specialise for string in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `T` is `std::string`, you will end up having to functions with identical signature, that's why your compiler is complaining. To overcome this, just make `compareVals` a template of its own. I would also suggest you make them `static`, so that you can call them without an object.

```
static int compareVals(std::string const& v1, std::string const& v2)
{
    //compare std::string
}

template<typename U>
static int compareVals(U v1, U v2)
{
    //compare everything else
}
```

In fact, `std::string` [does have built in relational operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp), so for your specific use case it might not be necessary to define a compare function like the above. At any rate, this approach might still be useful to avoid making the assumption operators are defined for every data type your `BinaryTree` might end up supporting in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much! Two questions:
1. In order to implement two different typenames, will I have to change the typename above my header? IE template <class t, u> ? 
2. Do the relational operators for string rank them alphabetically? I was told that it ranked them based on size, or something like that.

Comment: @user2779949 You won't need to change the signature of the class, don't worry. As for the comparison operators, they do what you would expect, i.e. rank the strings alphabetically