# Sort Items by parent relationship

Tags: c#, class, sorting

Coming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394626/display-comment-in-nested-way-like-gmail-comment/38397405) I ask myself if there is a easier way to sort a class like

```
public class ParentChild
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    int ParentID { get; set; }

    public ParentChild(int id, int pid)
    {
        ID = id;
        ParentID = pid;
    }
}
```

depending on it's parent-relationship.

e.g.

```
List<ParentChild> pcItems = new List<ParentChild>()
{           
    new ParentChild(1,0), // 0 is the default value in case of no parent
    new ParentChild(2,1),
    new ParentChild(3,2),
    new ParentChild(4,2),
    new ParentChild(5,1),
    new ParentChild(6,4),
    new ParentChild(7,1),
    new ParentChild(8,6),
    new ParentChild(9,3)
};
```

So the Items should have the following sort order: sorted first by child-relation and then by the ID.

```
1       // root
+-2
| +-3
| | +-9 // is the child of 3
| | 4   //is the 2nd child of 2 and has the higher ID conmpared to 3
| | +-6
| |   +-8
| 5
7
```

This question is not about to display data in hierarchical order. It's just about a simpler / not recursive / linq `OrderBy` / `Sort` compared to my answer in the linked post.

Comment: _"I've got a working method in my linked post, so no need to ask for efford"_ -- yes, there is. Each Stack Overflow question needs to stand on its own, so that if and when related questions are deleted, the question still makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you fix the constructor in `ParentChild` you should find that this works:

```
var lookup = pcItems.ToLookup(x => x.ParentID, x => x.ID);

Func<int, int, IEnumerable<string>> build = null;
build = (pid, level) =>
    lookup[pid]
        .SelectMany(id =>
            new [] { "".PadLeft(level * 4) + id.ToString() }
            .Concat(build(id, level + 1)));

IEnumerable<string> results = build(0, 0);
```

That gives you this:

[image: results]

It is recursive, but at least it is three lines of code. ;-)

---

To get just a sorted result:

```
var lookup = pcItems.ToLookup(x => x.ParentID, x => x.ID);
Func<int, int, IEnumerable<ParentChild>> build = null;
build = (pid, level) => lookup[pid]
                        .SelectMany(id => new[] { pcItems.Single(x => x.ID == id) }
                        .Concat(build(id, level + 1)));
IEnumerable<ParentChild> results = build(0, 0);
```

---

A slightly cleaner version:

```
var lookup = pcItems.ToLookup(x => x.ParentID);

Func<int, int, IEnumerable<ParentChild>> build = null;
build = (pid, level) =>
    lookup[pid].SelectMany(pc => new[] { pc }.Concat(build(pc.ID, level + 1)));

IEnumerable<ParentChild> results = build(0, 0);
```

Comment: @fubo - You just added lines to the tree output. That's a bit more onerous.

Comment: forget the lines, it's just about sorting

Comment: @fubo - Far enough. I think you'll find that you need recursion to get the proper sort order.

Comment: I added my modification to your answer - feel free to roll back

Comment: @fubo - I added a slightly cleaner version of the code under yours.