# Print Expression Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, expression-trees, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to print out an expression tree diagram for an infix expression. I already have methods that does the conversion of the infix expressions to post and prefix and returns them as strings. What I expect the output to be for the expression "1 + 3 - 6 ^ 7 * 5" is the following

```
              -
        +           *
    1      3     ^     5
                6  7
```

Preorder, Postorder and inorder traversal print does not seem to give me the right result. It traverses the tree / print the contents of the tree but does not distinguish between operators and operands. Is there a way to edit these traversals to print out the expression tree the right way (i.e, with spacing like the example above), or do I need to make a new traversal/print statement function that finds the root node (in this case the "-") and then sets the operators as roots and the operands as leaf nodes. How do I let the function know what operator in the expression is the root operator (ex, the "-" in the example above) and treat the rest as roots for sub trees?

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Binary Tree.
 */


public class DDBinaryTree<E>{

    protected Node<E> root;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty binary tree.
     */
    public DDBinaryTree() {

    }

    /**
     * Constructs a binary tree with given data in the root and the specified left and right
     * subtrees.
     *
     * @param data The data to store in root.
     * @param leftTree The left subtree.
     * @param rightTree The right subtree.
     */
    public DDBinaryTree(E data, DDBinaryTree<E> leftTree, DDBinaryTree<E> rightTree) {
        root = new Node<E>(data);
        if (leftTree!=null) {
            root.left = leftTree.root;
        }
        if (rightTree!=null) {
            root.right = rightTree.root;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a binary tree with a given node as its root.
     * @param root The root of the binary tree.
     */
    protected DDBinaryTree(Node<E> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the left subtree of this tree.
     * @return The left subtree, or null if it doesn't exist.
     */
    public DDBinaryTree<E> getLeftSubtree() {
        if (root!=null && root.left!=null) return new DDBinaryTree<E>(root.left);
        else return null;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the right subtree of this tree.
     * @return The right subtree, or null if it doesn't exist.
     */
    public DDBinaryTree<E> getRightSubtree() {
        if (root!=null && root.right!=null) return new DDBinaryTree<E>(root.right);
        else return null;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the data from the root node.
     * @return The data from the root, or null if tree is empty.
     */
    public E getData() {
        if (root!=null) return root.data;
        else return null;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if tree is empty
     * @return true if root is null, and false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return root == null;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if tree is a leaf.
     * @return true if this tree is a leaf, and false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return root != null && root.left == null && root.right == null;
    }

    /**
     * Performs a preorder traversal, executing the specified operation
     * on the data in each node it visits.
     *
     * @param visitOperation An operation to apply to the data of each visited node.
     */
    protected void preOrderTraversal(ProcessData<E> visitOperation) {
        preOrderTraversal(root, visitOperation);
    }

    private void preOrderTraversal(Node<E> node, ProcessData<E> visitOperation) {
        if (node==null) return;
        visitOperation.process(node.data);
        preOrderTraversal(node.left, visitOperation);
        preOrderTraversal(node.right, visitOperation);
    }

    /**
     * Performs a postorder traversal, executing the specified operation
     * on the data in each node it visits.
     *
     * @param visitOperation An operation to apply to the data of each visited node.
     */
    protected void postOrderTraversal(ProcessData<E> visitOperation) {
        postOrderTraversal(root, visitOperation);
    }

    private void postOrderTraversal(Node<E> node, ProcessData<E> visitOperation) {
        if (node==null) return;
        postOrderTraversal(node.left, visitOperation);
        postOrderTraversal(node.right, visitOperation);
        visitOperation.process(node.data);
    }

    /**
     * Performs a inorder traversal, executing the specified operation
     * on the data in each node it visits.
     *
     * @param visitOperation An operation to apply to the data of each visited node.
     */
    protected void inOrderTraversal(ProcessData<E> visitOperation) {
        inOrderTraversal(root, visitOperation);
    }

    private void inOrderTraversal(Node<E> node, ProcessData<E> visitOperation) {
        if (node==null) return;
        if (node.left != null && visitOperation instanceof PrePostProcess){
            ((PrePostProcess<E>)visitOperation).pre();

        }

        inOrderTraversal(node.left, visitOperation);
        visitOperation.process(node.data);
        inOrderTraversal(node.right, visitOperation);

        if (node.right != null && visitOperation instanceof PrePostProcess){
            ((PrePostProcess<E>)visitOperation).post();
        }
    }

    protected interface ProcessData<E> {
        void process(E data);
    }

    protected interface PrePostProcess<E> extends ProcessData<E> {
        void pre();
        void post();
    }

    protected static class Node<E> {
        protected E data;
        protected Node<E> left;
        protected Node<E> right;

        /**
         * Constructs a Node containing the given data.
         * @param data Data to store in node
         */
        public Node(E data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return data.toString();
        }
    }

}


import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Binary Search Tree
 */
public class DDBinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> extends DDBinaryTree implements Iterable<E> {
    static final int COUNT = 5;

    /**
     * Searches tree for target.
     *
     * @param target The element to look for.
     * @return true if in tree, and false otherwise
     */
    public boolean contains(E target) {
        return contains(root, target);
    }

    /**
     * Adds target to tree if it doesn't already exist.
     *
     * @param target The element to add.
     * @return true if target added and false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean add(E target) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node<E>(target);
            return true;
        }
        return add(root, target);
    }

    /**
     * Output contents in order.
     */
    public void printOrderedData() {
        inOrderTraversal(new ProcessData<E>() {
            @Override
            public void process(E data) {
                System.out.print(data + " ");
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean contains(Node<E> subtreeRoot, E target) {
        if (subtreeRoot == null) return false;
        if (target.compareTo(subtreeRoot.data) == 0) return true;
        else if (target.compareTo(subtreeRoot.data) < 0)
            return contains(subtreeRoot.left, target);
        else
            return contains(subtreeRoot.right, target);
    }


    private boolean add(Node<E> subtreeRoot, E target) {
        if (target.compareTo(subtreeRoot.data) == 0) return false;
        else if (target.compareTo(subtreeRoot.data) < 0) {
            if (subtreeRoot.left == null) {
                subtreeRoot.left = new Node<E>(target);
                return true;
            }
            return add(subtreeRoot.left, target);
        } else {
            if (subtreeRoot.right == null) {
                subtreeRoot.right = new Node<E>(target);
                return true;
            }
            return add(subtreeRoot.right, target);
        }
    }

}




public class Tester {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DDBinarySearchTree<Integer> integerSearchTree = new DDBinarySearchTree<>();
        DDBinarySearchTree<String> stringSearchTree = new DDBinarySearchTree<>();

        String stringToSplit = "1 + 3 - 6 ^ 7 * 5";

        //Splits up string and adds to stringSearchTree
        for (String str : stringToSplit.split(" ")) {
            stringSearchTree.add(str);
        }

        stringSearchTree.printOrderedData();


    }
}
```

In the printOrderedData method, you can change the traversal type from inorder to pre/postorder by typing in their methods

Comment: Is this just for debug output? If so, I'd suggest this style of output `-(+(1,3),*(^(6,7),5))` which is far easier to produce (trivial in comparison) and still shows the tree's structure.

Comment: No, I need help either tweaking the traversal algorithms or making a new method all together that evaluates an expression given and then prints out it's corresponding expression tree in a tree like diagram

Comment: And it has to be exactly like that diagram? There are other easier ways to print trees like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649027/how-do-i-print-out-a-tree-structure

Comment: Just something similar. Sorry, I did not see all of your first comment but that should be fine your output m the problem I am having is determining what's the root operator in the expression and then it's operator children and then the operand children. How do I let the function or tweaked traversal function hey the - is the root operator and then get the other operators and it's children all with spacing and such for the diagram.

Comment: My friend, let me introduce you to my favorite algorithm, the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). And generalized into [Operator precedence parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser).

Comment: Thank you, but I already am able to do the conversion of infix to postfix and prefix. I am trying to make a function that can find the root operator in an expression, set its as the root of the tree, then find the other operators in the expression, set those operators as children to the root, and find the operands associated with the operator roots and set them as leaf nodes.

Comment: I don't understand then. Once you've made a tree, the root is the root!

Comment: the traversals set the wrong root as the root. Inorder, postorder, and preorder set "1" as the root. The correct traversal should set the root operator "-" as the root. The problem is how to let the traversal know that hey the first element in the string is not the root, set the root to the root operator and work from the middle of the string out as assign operators as roots and their corresponding operands as children.

Comment: I think you don't understand what the algorithm I gave you does. If you have properly parsed it into a tree using the algorithm, then the root is the root.